# Is it worth using Python's re.compile?

Tags: python, regex

Is there any benefit in using compile for regular expressions in Python?

```
h = re.compile('hello')
h.match('hello world')
```

vs

```
re.match('hello', 'hello world')
```

Comment: Other then the fact that in 2.6 `re.sub` won't take a flags argument...

Comment: I just ran into a case where using `re.compile` gave a 10-50x improvement. The moral is that **if** you have a lot of regexes (more than MAXCACHE = 100) **and** you use them a lot of times each (and separated by more than MAXCACHE regexes in between, so that each one gets flushed from the cache: so using the same one a lot of times and then moving on to the next one doesn't count), **then** it would definitely help to compile them. Otherwise, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: One small thing to note is that for strings that do not need regex, the `in` string substring test is MUCH faster:
`>python -m timeit -s "import re" "re.match('hello', 'hello world')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.41 usec per loop`
     `>python -m timeit "x = 'hello' in 'hello world'"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0513 usec per loop`

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Interesting! Can you post an answer with an example which shows a 10x-50x improvement? Most answers given here actually show a 3x improvement in some precise cases, and in other cases nearly no improvement.

Comment: @Basj Done, posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile/61603344#61603344). I didn't bother to dig up what I was using Python for in December 2013, but the first straightforward thing I tried shows the same behaviour.

Answer (score 545, accepted):

I've had a lot of experience running a compiled regex 1000s of times versus compiling on-the-fly, and have not noticed any perceivable difference.  Obviously, this is anecdotal, and certainly not a great argument *against* compiling, but I've found the difference to be negligible.

EDIT:
After a quick glance at the actual Python 2.5 library code, I see that Python internally compiles AND CACHES regexes whenever you use them anyway (including calls to `re.match()`), so you're really only changing WHEN the regex gets compiled, and shouldn't be saving much time at all - only the time it takes to check the cache (a key lookup on an internal `dict` type).

From module re.py (comments are mine):

```
def match(pattern, string, flags=0):
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)

def _compile(*key):

    # Does cache check at top of function
    cachekey = (type(key[0]),) + key
    p = _cache.get(cachekey)
    if p is not None: return p

    # ...
    # Does actual compilation on cache miss
    # ...

    # Caches compiled regex
    if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:
        _cache.clear()
    _cache[cachekey] = p
    return p
```

I still often pre-compile regular expressions, but only to bind them to a nice, reusable name, not for any expected performance gain.

Comment: Your conclusion is inconsistent with your answer. If regexs are compiled and stored automatically there is no need in most cases to do it by hand.

Comment: J. F. Sebastian, it serves as a signal to the programmer that the regexp in question will be used a lot and is not meant to be a throwaway.

Comment: More than that, I'd say that if you don't want to suffer the compile & cache hit at some performance critical part of your application, you're best off to compile them before hand in a non-critical part of your application.

Comment: I can only add that _MAXCACHE = 100 in 2.5+ and 3.0.

Comment: I see the main advantage for using compiled regex if your re-using the same regex multiple times, thereby reducing the possibility for typos.  If your just calling it once then uncompiled is more readable.

Comment: So, the main difference will be when you are using lots of different regex (more than _MAXCACHE), some of them just once and others lots of times... then it's important to keep your compiled expressions for those that are used more so they're not flushed out of the cache when it's full.

Comment: @J.F. - Also, if you rely on compile-and-cache, who knows when the cache may be cleared, and then your regex will have to be recompiled.

Comment: If you're using python < 2.7 or 3.1, "re.sub" lacks a 'flags' parameter.  So if, say, you wanted to do case-insensitive re.sub, you're stuck doing ``re.compile("...", re.I).sub(...)``.

Comment: I think everyone missed the point overall even if you exclude typoes and the unknown timing of GC, the fact is if you need to run the same regex 100,000 times in a row not having to do a cache lookup 100,000 times is faster, lets think about it in the terms of parsing a large log file with regex, everyless step the lanauage has to take the better.

Comment: Another reason to avoid the compile step is to bring the regular expressions closer to the point of their use. I had a loop with tens of substitutions. Inventing names for the compiled regular expressions, and having to lookup the number of RE brackets at the beginning of the loop made the program less readable.

Comment: The entire cache is cleared if it gets saturated?!?!? I was going it'd be an LFU or LRU cache. Even more reason to compile patterns that I intend on using more than once. You never know if some other module that also imports re will be filling and clearing the cache.

Comment: @WojonsTech I thought of that too, but does it make any significant difference?

Comment: ""I've had a lot of experience running a compiled regex 1000s of times
versus compiling on-the-fly, and have not noticed any perceivable
difference. ..."*

That is too vague and misleading. Using a pre-compiled regex is 3x faster from the 2nd usage and even the first usage is 2x faster. Point.
The question is, if the the regex speed is crucial for a certain task. Otherwise direct use of the pattern ad hoc is **in most cases** more easy to write, read and debug.

Comment: I also think your answer is misleading: I run over 10,000 sentences and made a loop in them for iterating for regexes when the regexes weren't compiled and were calculated each time the prediction of a full run was 8 hours, after creating a dictionary according to index with compiled regex patterns I run the whole thing for 2 minutes. I can't understand this answer...

Comment: Python 3 [mentions it explicitely](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile): «The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to re.compile() and the module-level matching functions are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions» This should be added to the answer.

Answer (score 174):

For me, the biggest benefit to `re.compile` is being able to separate definition of the regex from its use.

Even a simple expression such as `0|[1-9][0-9]*` (integer in base 10 without leading zeros) can be complex enough that you'd rather not have to retype it, check if you made any typos, and later have to recheck if there are typos when you start debugging. Plus, it's nicer to use a variable name such as num or num_b10 than `0|[1-9][0-9]*`.

It's certainly possible to store strings and pass them to re.match; however, that's *less* readable:

```
num = "..."
# then, much later:
m = re.match(num, input)
```

Versus compiling:

```
num = re.compile("...")
# then, much later:
m = num.match(input)
```

Though it is fairly close, the last line of the second feels more natural and simpler when used repeatedly.

Comment: I agree with this answer; oftentimes using re.compile results in more, not less readable code.

Comment: Sometimes the opposite is true, though - e.g. if you define the regex in one place and use its matching groups in another far-away place.

Comment: @KenWilliams Not necessarily, a well named regex for a specific purpose should be clear even when used far from the original definition.  For example `us_phone_number` or `social_security_number` etc.

Comment: @BrianM.Sheldon naming the regex well doesn't really help you know what its various capturing groups represent.

Answer (score 101):

FWIW:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "import re" "re.match('hello', 'hello world')"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.82 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s "import re; h=re.compile('hello')" "h.match('hello world')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 usec per loop
```

so, if you're going to be using  the *same* regex a lot, it may be worth it to do `re.compile` (especially for more complex regexes).

The standard arguments against premature optimization apply, but I don't think you really lose much clarity/straightforwardness by using `re.compile` if you suspect that your regexps may become a performance bottleneck.

**Update:**

Under Python 3.6 (I suspect the above timings were done using Python 2.x) and 2018 hardware (MacBook Pro), I now get the following timings:

```
% python -m timeit -s "import re" "re.match('hello', 'hello world')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.661 usec per loop

% python -m timeit -s "import re; h=re.compile('hello')" "h.match('hello world')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.285 usec per loop

% python -m timeit -s "import re" "h=re.compile('hello'); h.match('hello world')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.65 usec per loop

% python --version
Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

I also added a case (notice the quotation mark differences between the last two runs) that shows that `re.match(x, ...)` is literally [roughly] equivalent to `re.compile(x).match(...)`, i.e. no behind-the-scenes caching of the compiled representation seems to happen.

Comment: Major problems with your methodology here, since the setup argument is NOT including in the timing.  Thus, you've removed the compilation time from the second example, and just average it out in the first example.  This doesn't mean the first example compiles every time.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is not a fair comparison of the two cases.

Comment: I see what you mean, but isn't that exactly what would happen in an actual application where the regexp is used many times?

Comment: @dF: You're right, IF you only care about performance in one particular part of your code, and you're able to pre-compile the regex in another part.  Otherwise, you need to time the re.compile call and include that in the second number for it to be a fair comparison.

Comment: @Triptych, @Kiv: The whole point of compiling regexps separate from use *is* to minimize compilation; removing it from the timing is exactly what dF should have done, because it represents real-world use most accurately.  Compilation time is especially irrelevant with the way timeit.py does its timings here; it does several runs and only reports the shortest one, at which point the compiled regexp is cached.

The extra cost you're seeing here is not the cost of compiling the regexp, but the cost of looking it up in the compiled regexp cache (a dictionary).

Comment: This test is misleading. The _total_ execution time of both tests would be equivalent in real-world code. Compiling first lets you decide _when_ you eat up those CPU cycles, not _if_.

Comment: @Triptych Should the `import re` be moved out of setup? It's all about where you want to measure. If I run a python script numerous times, it would have the `import re` time hit. When comparing the two it is important to separate the two lines for timing. Yes as you say it is when you will have the time hit. The comparison shows that either you take the time hit once and repeat the lesser time hit by compiling or you take the hit each time assuming the cache gets cleared between calls, which as it has been pointed out could happen. Adding a timing of `h=re.compile('hello')` would help clarify.

Comment: If you're on a Linux-like operating system, just do `time python -m...` instead of just `python -m...`, and your results are like mine, you'll see that pre-compiling is indeed a significant performance win (for me, first is 3.87s CPU total, second is 1.64s.

Comment: The regex is a simple string. The time result is regex search time+ cache search time for first timeit. Leaving the initial compile time and other deficiencies of this method aside, If we were to dramatically increase the regex time, Would the difference between the two timeits warrant pre-compile?

Comment: Running `python -m timeit -s "import re; n=1000" "h=re.compile('hello'); [ h.match('hello world') for i in range(n) ]"` vs `python -m timeit -s "import re; n=1000" "[ re.match('hello', 'hello world') for i in range(n) ]"` still gives x2 faster running time for pre-compiled regex. This argues against previous comments saying it's an unfair comparison. I suggest including those benchmarks in the answer.

Answer (score 45):

Here's a simple test case:

```
~$ for x in 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000; do python -m timeit -n $x -s 'import re' 're.match("[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}", "123-123-1234")'; done
1 loops, best of 3: 3.1 usec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 2.41 usec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.24 usec per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 2.21 usec per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 2.23 usec per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.24 usec per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 2.31 usec per loop
```

with re.compile:

```
~$ for x in 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000; do python -m timeit -n $x -s 'import re' 'r = re.compile("[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}")' 'r.match("123-123-1234")'; done
1 loops, best of 3: 1.91 usec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 0.691 usec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 0.701 usec per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 0.684 usec per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 0.682 usec per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 0.694 usec per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.702 usec per loop
```

So, it would seem to compiling is faster with this simple case, *even if you only match once*.

Comment: Which version of Python is this?

Comment: it doesn't really matter, the point is to try the benchmark in the environment where you'll be running the code

Comment: For me the performance is almost exactly the same for 1000 loops or more. The compiled version is faster for 1-100 loops. (On both pythons 2.7 and 3.4).

Comment: On my Python 2.7.3 setup there is hardly any difference. Sometimes compile is faster, sometimes ist's slower. The difference is always <5%, so I count the difference as measuring uncertainty, since the device only has one CPU.

Comment: In Python 3.4.3 seen in two separate runs: using compiled was even slower than not compiled.

Comment: Running on python 3.6.5 on Ubuntu 16.04, the result are similar for the two statements.

Answer (score 23):

I just tried this myself. For the simple case of parsing a number out of a string and summing it, using a compiled regular expression object is about twice as fast as using the `re` methods.

As others have pointed out, the `re` methods (including `re.compile`) look up the regular expression string in a cache of previously compiled expressions. Therefore, in the normal case, the extra cost of using the `re` methods is simply the cost of the cache lookup.

However, examination of the [code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#1IKf2ZWr9OM/tools/third_party/python_26/Lib/re.py&q=lang:python%20re.py&sa=N&cd=4&ct=rc), shows the cache is limited to 100 expressions. This begs the question, how painful is it to overflow the cache? The code contains an internal interface to the regular expression compiler, `re.sre_compile.compile`. If we call it, we bypass the cache. It turns out to be about two orders of magnitude slower for a basic regular expression, such as `r'\w+\s+([0-9_]+)\s+\w*'`.

Here's my test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
import time

def timed(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        t = time.time()
        result = func(*args)
        t = time.time() - t
        print '%s took %.3f seconds.' % (func.func_name, t)
        return result
    return wrapper

regularExpression = r'\w+\s+([0-9_]+)\s+\w*'
testString = "average    2 never"

@timed
def noncompiled():
    a = 0
    for x in xrange(1000000):
        m = re.match(regularExpression, testString)
        a += int(m.group(1))
    return a

@timed
def compiled():
    a = 0
    rgx = re.compile(regularExpression)
    for x in xrange(1000000):
        m = rgx.match(testString)
        a += int(m.group(1))
    return a

@timed
def reallyCompiled():
    a = 0
    rgx = re.sre_compile.compile(regularExpression)
    for x in xrange(1000000):
        m = rgx.match(testString)
        a += int(m.group(1))
    return a


@timed
def compiledInLoop():
    a = 0
    for x in xrange(1000000):
        rgx = re.compile(regularExpression)
        m = rgx.match(testString)
        a += int(m.group(1))
    return a

@timed
def reallyCompiledInLoop():
    a = 0
    for x in xrange(10000):
        rgx = re.sre_compile.compile(regularExpression)
        m = rgx.match(testString)
        a += int(m.group(1))
    return a

r1 = noncompiled()
r2 = compiled()
r3 = reallyCompiled()
r4 = compiledInLoop()
r5 = reallyCompiledInLoop()
print "r1 = ", r1
print "r2 = ", r2
print "r3 = ", r3
print "r4 = ", r4
print "r5 = ", r5
</pre>
And here is the output on my machine:
<pre>
$ regexTest.py 
noncompiled took 4.555 seconds.
compiled took 2.323 seconds.
reallyCompiled took 2.325 seconds.
compiledInLoop took 4.620 seconds.
reallyCompiledInLoop took 4.074 seconds.
r1 =  2000000
r2 =  2000000
r3 =  2000000
r4 =  2000000
r5 =  20000
```

The 'reallyCompiled' methods use the internal interface, which bypasses the cache. Note the one that compiles on each loop iteration is only iterated 10,000 times, not one million.

Comment: I agree with you that compiled regexes run much faster than non-compiled. I run over 10,000 sentences and made a loop in them for iterating for regexes when the regexes weren't compiled and were calculated each time the prediction of a full run was 8 hours, after creating a dictionary according to index with compiled regex patterns I run the whole thing for 2 minutes. I can't understand the answers above...

Answer (score 20):

Here is an example where using `re.compile` is over 50 times faster, as [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile#comment108948583_452104).

The point is just the same as what I made in the comment above, namely, using `re.compile` can be a significant advantage when your usage is such as to not benefit much from the compilation cache. This happens at least in one particular case (that I ran into in practice), namely when all of the following are true:

- You have a lot of regex patterns (more than `re._MAXCACHE`, whose [default](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9d74658f0a6e8a9b8d6dcf199dda886f35c6ad68/Lib/re.py#L288) is currently 512), and
- you use these regexes a lot of times, and
- you consecutive usages of the same pattern are separated by more than `re._MAXCACHE` other regexes in between, so that each one gets flushed from the cache between consecutive usages.

```py
import re
import time

def setup(N=1000):
    # Patterns 'a.*a', 'a.*b', ..., 'z.*z'
    patterns = [chr(i) + '.*' + chr(j)
                    for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)
                    for j in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1)]
    # If this assertion below fails, just add more (distinct) patterns.
    # assert(re._MAXCACHE < len(patterns))
    # N strings. Increase N for larger effect.
    strings = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'] * N
    return (patterns, strings)

def without_compile():
    print('Without re.compile:')
    patterns, strings = setup()
    print('searching')
    count = 0
    for s in strings:
        for pat in patterns:
            count += bool(re.search(pat, s))
    return count

def without_compile_cache_friendly():
    print('Without re.compile, cache-friendly order:')
    patterns, strings = setup()
    print('searching')
    count = 0
    for pat in patterns:
        for s in strings:
            count += bool(re.search(pat, s))
    return count

def with_compile():
    print('With re.compile:')
    patterns, strings = setup()
    print('compiling')
    compiled = [re.compile(pattern) for pattern in patterns]
    print('searching')
    count = 0
    for s in strings:
        for regex in compiled:
            count += bool(regex.search(s))
    return count

start = time.time()
print(with_compile())
d1 = time.time() - start
print(f'-- That took {d1:.2f} seconds.\n')

start = time.time()
print(without_compile_cache_friendly())
d2 = time.time() - start
print(f'-- That took {d2:.2f} seconds.\n')

start = time.time()
print(without_compile())
d3 = time.time() - start
print(f'-- That took {d3:.2f} seconds.\n')

print(f'Ratio: {d3/d1:.2f}')
```

Example output I get on my laptop (Python 3.7.7):

```
With re.compile:
compiling
searching
676000
-- That took 0.33 seconds.

Without re.compile, cache-friendly order:
searching
676000
-- That took 0.67 seconds.

Without re.compile:
searching
676000
-- That took 23.54 seconds.

Ratio: 70.89
```

I didn't bother with `timeit` as the difference is so stark, but I get qualitatively similar numbers each time. Note that even without `re.compile`, using the same regex multiple times and moving on to the next one wasn't so bad (only about 2 times as slow as with `re.compile`), but in the other order (looping through many regexes), it is significantly worse, as expected. Also, increasing the cache size works too: simply setting `re._MAXCACHE = len(patterns)` in `setup()` above (of course I don't recommend doing such things in production as names with underscores are conventionally “private”) drops the ~23 seconds back down to ~0.7 seconds, which also matches our understanding.

Comment: PS: if I use *only* 3 regex patterns in my whole code, each of them used (without any specific order) hundreds of time, the regex cache will keep the precompiled regex automatically, is that right?

Comment: @Basj I think you could just try it and see :) But the answer, I'm pretty sure, is yes: the only additional cost in that case AFAICT is just that of simply [looking up the pattern in the cache](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9d74658f0a6e8a9b8d6dcf199dda886f35c6ad68/Lib/re.py#L294). Note also that the cache is global (module-level), so in principle you could have some dependency library doing regex searches in between yours, so it's hard to be fully confident that your program only ever uses 3 (or whatever number of) regex patterns, but it would be pretty weird to be otherwise :)

Answer (score 17):

I agree with Honest Abe that the `match(...)` in the given examples are different.  They are not a one-to-one comparisons and thus, outcomes are vary.  To simplify my reply, I use A, B, C, D for those functions in question.  Oh yes, we are dealing with 4 functions in `re.py` instead of 3.

Running this piece of code:

```
h = re.compile('hello')                   # (A)
h.match('hello world')                    # (B)
```

is same as running this code:

```
re.match('hello', 'hello world')          # (C)
```

Because, when looked into the source `re.py`, (A + B) means:

```
h = re._compile('hello')                  # (D)
h.match('hello world')
```

and (C) is actually:

```
re._compile('hello').match('hello world')
```

So, (C) is not the same as (B).  In fact, (C) calls (B) after calling (D) which is also called by (A).  In other words, `(C) = (A) + (B)`.  Therefore, comparing (A + B) inside a loop has the same result as (C) inside a loop.

George's `regexTest.py` proved this for us.

```
noncompiled took 4.555 seconds.           # (C) in a loop
compiledInLoop took 4.620 seconds.        # (A + B) in a loop
compiled took 2.323 seconds.              # (A) once + (B) in a loop
```

Everyone's interest is, how to get the result of 2.323 seconds.  In order to make sure `compile(...)` only gets called once, we need to store the compiled regex object in memory.  If we are using a class, we could store the object and reuse when every time our function gets called.

```
class Foo:
    regex = re.compile('hello')
    def my_function(text)
        return regex.match(text)
```

If we are not using class (which is my request today), then I have no comment.  I'm still learning to use a global variable in Python, and I know a global variable is a bad thing.

One more point, I believe that using `(A) + (B)` approach has an upper hand.  Here are some facts as I observed (please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. Calls A once, it will do one search in the `_cache` followed by one `sre_compile.compile()` to create a regex object.  Calls A twice, it will do two searches and one compile (because the regex object is cached).
2. If the `_cache` gets flushed in between, then the regex object is released from memory and Python needs to compile again. (someone suggests that Python won't recompile.)
3. If we keep the regex object by using (A), the regex object will still get into _cache and get flushed somehow.  But our code keeps a reference on it and the regex object will not be released from memory.  Those, Python need not to compile again.
4. The 2 seconds difference in George's test compiled loop vs compiled is mainly the time required to build the key and search the _cache.  It doesn't mean the compile time of regex.
5. George's reallycompile test show what happens if it really re-do the compile every time: it will be 100x slower (he reduced the loop from 1,000,000 to 10,000).

Here are the only cases that (A + B) is better than (C):

1. If we can cache a reference of the regex object inside a class.
2. If we need to calls (B) repeatedly (inside a loop or multiple times), we must cache the reference to the regex object outside the loop.

Case that (C) is good enough:

1. We cannot cache a reference.
2. We only use it once in a while.
3. In overall, we don't have too many regex (assume the compiled one never get flushed)

Just a recap, here are the A B C:

```
h = re.compile('hello')                   # (A)
h.match('hello world')                    # (B)
re.match('hello', 'hello world')          # (C)
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 12):

Mostly, there is little difference whether you use *re.compile* or not.  Internally, all of the functions are implemented in terms of a compile step:

```
def match(pattern, string, flags=0):
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)

def fullmatch(pattern, string, flags=0):
    return _compile(pattern, flags).fullmatch(string)

def search(pattern, string, flags=0):
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)

def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
    return _compile(pattern, flags).subn(repl, string, count)

def split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0):
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)

def findall(pattern, string, flags=0):
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)

def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):
    return _compile(pattern, flags).finditer(string)
```

In addition, re.compile() bypasses the extra indirection and caching logic:

```
_cache = {}

_pattern_type = type(sre_compile.compile("", 0))

_MAXCACHE = 512
def _compile(pattern, flags):
    # internal: compile pattern
    try:
        p, loc = _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
        if loc is None or loc == _locale.setlocale(_locale.LC_CTYPE):
            return p
    except KeyError:
        pass
    if isinstance(pattern, _pattern_type):
        if flags:
            raise ValueError(
                "cannot process flags argument with a compiled pattern")
        return pattern
    if not sre_compile.isstring(pattern):
        raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    if not (flags & DEBUG):
        if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:
            _cache.clear()
        if p.flags & LOCALE:
            if not _locale:
                return p
            loc = _locale.setlocale(_locale.LC_CTYPE)
        else:
            loc = None
        _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags] = p, loc
    return p
```

In addition to the small speed benefit from using *re.compile*, people also like the readability that comes from naming potentially complex pattern specifications and separating them from the business logic where there are applied:

```
#### Patterns ############################################################
number_pattern = re.compile(r'\d+(\.\d*)?')    # Integer or decimal number
assign_pattern = re.compile(r':=')             # Assignment operator
identifier_pattern = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]+')  # Identifiers
whitespace_pattern = re.compile(r'[\t ]+')     # Spaces and tabs

#### Applications ########################################################

if whitespace_pattern.match(s): business_logic_rule_1()
if assign_pattern.match(s): business_logic_rule_2()
```

Note, one other respondent incorrectly believed that *pyc* files stored compiled patterns directly; however, in reality they are rebuilt each time when the PYC is loaded:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> with open('tmp.pyc', 'rb') as f:
        f.read(8)
        dis(marshal.load(f))

  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (re)
              9 STORE_NAME               0 (re)

  3          12 LOAD_NAME                0 (re)
             15 LOAD_ATTR                1 (compile)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('[aeiou]{2,5}')
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 STORE_NAME               2 (lc_vowels)
             27 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

The above disassembly comes from the PYC file for a `tmp.py` containing:

```
import re
lc_vowels = re.compile(r'[aeiou]{2,5}')
```

Comment: is the `"` in `def search(pattern, string, flags=0):"` a typo?

Comment: Note that if `pattern` is already a compiled pattern, the caching overhead becomes significant : hashing a `SRE_Pattern` is expensive and the pattern is never written to cache, so the lookup fails each time with a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 7):

There is one addition perk of using re.compile(), in the form of adding comments to my regex patterns using re.VERBOSE

```
pattern = '''
hello[ ]world    # Some info on my pattern logic. [ ] to recognize space
'''

re.search(pattern, 'hello world', re.VERBOSE)
```

Although this does not affect the speed of running your code, I like to do it this way as it is part of my commenting habit. I throughly dislike spending time trying to remember the logic that went behind my code 2 months down the line when I want to make modifications.

Comment: I've edited your answer. I think mentioning `re.VERBOSE` is worthwhile, and it does add something that the other answers seem to have left out. However, leading your answer with "I'm posting here because I can't comment yet" is sure to get it deleted. Please don't use the answers box for anything other than answers. You're only one or two good answers away from being able to comment anywhere (50 rep), so please just be patient. Putting comments in answer boxes when you know you shouldn't won't get you there any faster. It will get you downvotes and deleted answers.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

The sequence

```
prog = re.compile(pattern)
result = prog.match(string)
```

is equivalent to

```
result = re.match(pattern, string)
```

but using `re.compile()` and saving the resulting regular expression object for reuse is more efficient when the expression will be used several times in a single program.

So my conclusion is, if you are going to match the same pattern for many different texts, you better precompile it.

Answer (score 5):

In general, I find it is easier to use flags (at least easier to remember how), like `re.I` when compiling patterns than to use flags inline.

```
>>> foo_pat = re.compile('foo',re.I)
>>> foo_pat.findall('some string FoO bar')
['FoO']
```

vs

```
>>> re.findall('(?i)foo','some string FoO bar')
['FoO']
```

Comment: You could use flags as the third argument of the `re.findall` too anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Using the given examples:

```
h = re.compile('hello')
h.match('hello world')
```

The *match* method in the example above is not the same as the one used below:

```
re.match('hello', 'hello world')
```

[re.compile()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.compile) returns a [regular expression object](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#regular-expression-objects), which means `h` is a regex object.

The regex object has its own [*match*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.regex.match) method with the optional *pos* and *endpos* parameters:

[`regex.match(string[, pos[, endpos]])`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.regex.match)

**pos**

> The optional second parameter *pos* gives an index in the string where
>   the search is to start; it defaults to 0. This is not completely
>   equivalent to slicing the string; the `'^'` pattern character matches at
>   the real beginning of the string and at positions just after a
>   newline, but not necessarily at the index where the search is to
>   start.

**endpos**

> The optional parameter *endpos* limits how far the string will be
>   searched; it will be as if the string is *endpos* characters long, so
>   only the characters from *pos* to `endpos - 1` will be searched for a
>   match. If *endpos* is less than *pos*, no match will be found; otherwise,
>   if *rx* is a compiled regular expression object, `rx.search(string, 0,
>   50)` is equivalent to `rx.search(string[:50], 0)`.

The regex object's *search*, *findall*, and *finditer* methods also support these parameters.

[`re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#re.match) does not support them as you can see,
nor does its *search*, *findall*, and *finditer* counterparts.

A [match object](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#match-objects) has attributes that complement these parameters:

**match.pos**

> The value of pos which was passed to the search() or match() method of
>   a regex object. This is the index into the string at which the RE
>   engine started looking for a match.

**match.endpos**

> The value of endpos which was passed to the search() or match() method
>   of a regex object. This is the index into the string beyond which the
>   RE engine will not go.

---

A [regex object](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#regular-expression-objects) has two unique, possibly useful, attributes:

**regex.groups**

> The number of capturing groups in the pattern.

**regex.groupindex**

> A dictionary mapping any symbolic group names defined by (?P) to
>   group numbers. The dictionary is empty if no symbolic groups were used
>   in the pattern.

---

And finally, a [match object](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html?highlight=re.sub#match-objects) has this attribute:

**match.re**

> The regular expression object whose match() or search() method
>   produced this match instance.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the performance.

Using `compile` helps me to distinguish the concepts of
*1. module(re)*,
*2. regex object*
*3. match object*
When I started learning regex

```
#regex object
regex_object = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+')
#match object
match_object = regex_object.search('1.Hello')
#matching content
match_object.group()
output:
Out[60]: 'Hello'
V.S.
re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+','1.Hello').group()
Out[61]: 'Hello'
```

As a complement, I made an exhaustive cheatsheet of module `re` for your reference.

```
regex = {
'brackets':{'single_character': ['[]', '.', {'negate':'^'}],
            'capturing_group' : ['()','(?:)', '(?!)' '|', '\\', 'backreferences and named group'],
            'repetition'      : ['{}', '*?', '+?', '??', 'greedy v.s. lazy ?']},
'lookaround' :{'lookahead'  : ['(?=...)', '(?!...)'],
            'lookbehind' : ['(?<=...)','(?<!...)'],
            'caputuring' : ['(?P<name>...)', '(?P=name)', '(?:)'],},
'escapes':{'anchor'          : ['^', '\b', '$'],
          'non_printable'   : ['\n', '\t', '\r', '\f', '\v'],
          'shorthand'       : ['\d', '\w', '\s']},
'methods': {['search', 'match', 'findall', 'finditer'],
              ['split', 'sub']},
'match_object': ['group','groups', 'groupdict','start', 'end', 'span',]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Performance difference aside, using re.compile and using the compiled regular expression object to do match (whatever regular expression related operations) makes the semantics clearer to Python run-time.

I had some painful experience of debugging some simple code:

```
compare = lambda s, p: re.match(p, s)
```

and later I'd use compare in

```
[x for x in data if compare(patternPhrases, x[columnIndex])]
```

where `patternPhrases` is supposed to be a variable containing regular expression string, `x[columnIndex]` is a variable containing string.

I had trouble that `patternPhrases` did not match some expected string!

But if I used the re.compile form:

```
compare = lambda s, p: p.match(s)
```

then in

```
[x for x in data if compare(patternPhrases, x[columnIndex])]
```

Python would have complained that "string does not have attribute of match", as by positional argument mapping in `compare`, `x[columnIndex]` is used as regular expression!, when I actually meant

```
compare = lambda p, s: p.match(s)
```

In my case, using re.compile is more explicit of the purpose of regular expression, when it's value is hidden to naked eyes, thus I could get more help from Python run-time checking.

So the moral of my lesson is that when the regular expression is not just literal string, then I should use re.compile to let Python to help me to assert my assumption.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative answer, as I see that it hasn't been mentioned before, I'll go ahead and quote the [Python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#performing-matches):

> Should you use these module-level functions, or should you get the pattern and call its methods yourself? If you’re accessing a regex within a loop, pre-compiling it will save a few function calls. Outside of loops, there’s not much difference thanks to the internal cache.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, compiling does prove more efficient for me (Python 2.5.2 on Win XP):

```
import re
import time

rgx = re.compile('(\w+)\s+[0-9_]?\s+\w*')
str = "average    2 never"
a = 0

t = time.time()

for i in xrange(1000000):
    if re.match('(\w+)\s+[0-9_]?\s+\w*', str):
    #~ if rgx.match(str):
        a += 1

print time.time() - t
```

Running the above code once as is, and once with the two `if` lines commented the other way around, the compiled regex is twice as fast

Comment: Same issue as with dF's performance comparison.  It's not really fair unless you include the performance cost of the compile statement itself.

Comment: Carl, I disagree. The compile is only executed once, while the matching loop is executed a million times

Comment: @eliben: I agree with Carl Meyer. The compilation takes place in both cases. Triptych mentions that caching is involved, so in an optimal case (re stays in cache) both approaches are O(n+1), although the +1 part is kind of hidden when you don't use re.compile explicitly.

Comment: Don't write your own benchmarking code.  Learn to use timeit.py, which is included in the standard distribution.

Comment: How much of that time are you recreating the pattern string in the for loop. This overhead can't be trivial.

Answer (score 3):

I ran this test before stumbling upon the discussion here.  However, having run it I thought I'd at least post my results.

I stole and bastardized the example in Jeff Friedl's "Mastering Regular Expressions".  This is on a macbook running OSX 10.6 (2Ghz intel core 2 duo, 4GB ram).  Python version is 2.6.1.

**Run 1 - using re.compile**

```
import re 
import time 
import fpformat
Regex1 = re.compile('^(a|b|c|d|e|f|g)+$') 
Regex2 = re.compile('^[a-g]+$')
TimesToDo = 1000
TestString = "" 
for i in range(1000):
    TestString += "abababdedfg"
StartTime = time.time() 
for i in range(TimesToDo):
    Regex1.search(TestString) 
Seconds = time.time() - StartTime 
print "Alternation takes " + fpformat.fix(Seconds,3) + " seconds"

StartTime = time.time() 
for i in range(TimesToDo):
    Regex2.search(TestString) 
Seconds = time.time() - StartTime 
print "Character Class takes " + fpformat.fix(Seconds,3) + " seconds"

Alternation takes 2.299 seconds
Character Class takes 0.107 seconds
```

**Run 2 - Not using re.compile**

```
import re 
import time 
import fpformat

TimesToDo = 1000
TestString = "" 
for i in range(1000):
    TestString += "abababdedfg"
StartTime = time.time() 
for i in range(TimesToDo):
    re.search('^(a|b|c|d|e|f|g)+$',TestString) 
Seconds = time.time() - StartTime 
print "Alternation takes " + fpformat.fix(Seconds,3) + " seconds"

StartTime = time.time() 
for i in range(TimesToDo):
    re.search('^[a-g]+$',TestString) 
Seconds = time.time() - StartTime 
print "Character Class takes " + fpformat.fix(Seconds,3) + " seconds"

Alternation takes 2.508 seconds
Character Class takes 0.109 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer might be arriving late but is an interesting find. Using compile can really save you time if you are planning on using the regex multiple times (this is also mentioned in the docs). Below you can see that using a compiled regex is the fastest when the match method is directly called on it. passing a compiled regex to re.match makes it even slower and passing re.match with the patter string is somewhere in the middle.

```
>>> ipr = r'\D+((([0-2][0-5]?[0-5]?)\.){3}([0-2][0-5]?[0-5]?))\D+'
>>> average(*timeit.repeat("re.match(ipr, 'abcd100.10.255.255 ')", globals={'ipr': ipr, 're': re}))
1.5077415757028423
>>> ipr = re.compile(ipr)
>>> average(*timeit.repeat("re.match(ipr, 'abcd100.10.255.255 ')", globals={'ipr': ipr, 're': re}))
1.8324008992184038
>>> average(*timeit.repeat("ipr.match('abcd100.10.255.255 ')", globals={'ipr': ipr, 're': re}))
0.9187896518778871
```

Answer (score 2):

I really respect all the above answers. From my opinion
Yes! For sure it is worth to use re.compile instead of compiling the regex, again and again, every time.

> Using **re.compile** makes your code more dynamic, as you can call the already compiled regex, instead of compiling again and aagain. This thing benefits you in cases:

1. Processor Efforts
2. Time Complexity.
3. Makes regex Universal.(can be used in findall, search, match)
4. And makes your program looks cool.

***Example :***

```
  example_string = "The room number of her room is 26A7B."
  find_alpha_numeric_string = re.compile(r"\b\w+\b")
```

## Using in Findall

```
 find_alpha_numeric_string.findall(example_string)
```

## Using in search

```
  find_alpha_numeric_string.search(example_string)
```

> > Similarly you can use it for: **Match and Substitute**

Answer (score 2):

Although the two approaches are comparable in terms of speed, you should know that there still *is* some negligible time difference which might be of your concern if you're dealing with millions of iterations.

The following speed test:

```py
import re
import time

SIZE = 100_000_000

start = time.time()
foo = re.compile('foo')
[foo.search('bar') for _ in range(SIZE)]
print('compiled:  ', time.time() - start)

start = time.time()
[re.search('foo', 'bar') for _ in range(SIZE)]
print('uncompiled:', time.time() - start)
```

gives these results:

```
compiled:   14.647532224655151
uncompiled: 61.483458042144775
```

The compiled approach is on my PC (with Python 3.7.0) consistently about 4 times faster.

As explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#module-level-functions):

> If you’re accessing a regex within a loop, pre-compiling it will save a few function calls. Outside of loops, there’s not much difference thanks to the internal cache.

Answer (score 1):

(months later) it's easy to add your own cache around re.match,
or anything else for that matter --

```
""" Re.py: Re.match = re.match + cache  
    efficiency: re.py does this already (but what's _MAXCACHE ?)
    readability, inline / separate: matter of taste
"""

import re

cache = {}
_re_type = type( re.compile( "" ))

def match( pattern, str, *opt ):
    """ Re.match = re.match + cache re.compile( pattern ) 
    """
    if type(pattern) == _re_type:
        cpat = pattern
    elif pattern in cache:
        cpat = cache[pattern]
    else:
        cpat = cache[pattern] = re.compile( pattern, *opt )
    return cpat.match( str )

# def search ...
```

A wibni, wouldn't it be nice if: cachehint( size= ), cacheinfo() -> size, hits, nclear ...

Answer (score 1):

> I've had a lot of experience running a compiled regex 1000s
>   of times versus compiling on-the-fly, and have not noticed
>   any perceivable difference

The votes on the accepted answer leads to the assumption that what @Triptych says is true for all cases. This is not necessarily true. One big difference is when you have to decide whether to accept a regex string or a compiled regex object as a parameter to a function:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="""
... import re
... f=lambda x, y: x.match(y)       # accepts compiled regex as parameter
... h=re.compile('hello')
... """, stmt="f(h, 'hello world')")
0.32881879806518555
>>> timeit.timeit(setup="""
... import re
... f=lambda x, y: re.compile(x).match(y)   # compiles when called
... """, stmt="f('hello', 'hello world')")
0.809190034866333
```

It is always better to compile your regexs in case you need to reuse them.

Note the example in the timeit above simulates creation of a compiled regex object once at import time versus "on-the-fly" when required for a match.

Answer (score 1):

on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.10.6

$ for x in 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000; do python -m timeit -n $x -s 'import re' 're.match("[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}", "123-123-1234")'; done
1 loop, best of 5: 972 nsec per loop
:0: UserWarning: The test results are likely unreliable. The worst time (186 usec) was more than four times slower than the best time (972 nsec).
10 loops, best of 5: 819 nsec per loop
:0: UserWarning: The test results are likely unreliable. The worst time (13.9 usec) was more than four times slower than the best time (819 nsec).
100 loops, best of 5: 763 nsec per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 699 nsec per loop
10000 loops, best of 5: 653 nsec per loop
100000 loops, best of 5: 655 nsec per loop
1000000 loops, best of 5: 656 nsec per loop

$ for x in 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000; do python -m timeit -n $x -s 'import re' 'r = re.compile("[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}")' 'r.match("123-123-1234")'; done
1 loop, best of 5: 985 nsec per loop
:0: UserWarning: The test results are likely unreliable. The worst time (134 usec) was more than four times slower than the best time (985 nsec).
10 loops, best of 5: 775 nsec per loop
:0: UserWarning: The test results are likely unreliable. The worst time (13.9 usec) was more than four times slower than the best time (775 nsec).
100 loops, best of 5: 756 nsec per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 701 nsec per loop
10000 loops, best of 5: 704 nsec per loop
100000 loops, best of 5: 654 nsec per loop
1000000 loops, best of 5: 651 nsec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions are compiled before being used when using the second version.  If you are going to executing it many times it is definatly better to compile it first.  If not compiling every time you match for one off's is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. You often see people use re.compile without reason. It lessens readability. But sure there are lots of times when pre-compiling the expression is called for. Like when you use it repeated times in a loop or some such.

It's like everything about programming (everything in life actually). Apply common sense.

Comment: As far as I can tell from my brief flick through, *Python in a Nutshell* doesn't mention use without re.compile(), which made me curious.

Comment: The regex object adds one more object to the context. As I said, there exists many situations where re.compile() has its place. The example given by the OP is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

#### Legibility/cognitive load preference

To me, the main gain is that I only need to remember, and read, **one** form of the complicated regex API syntax - the `<compiled_pattern>.method(xxx)` form rather than that **and** the `re.func(<pattern>, xxx)` form.

The `re.compile(<pattern>)` is a bit of extra boilerplate, true.

But where regex are concerned, that extra compile step is unlikely to be a big cause of cognitive load.  And in fact, on complicated patterns, you might even gain clarity from separating the declaration from whatever regex method you then invoke on it.

I tend to first tune complicated patterns in a website like Regex101, or even in a separate minimal test script, then bring them into my code, so separating the declaration from its use fits my workflow as well.

Answer (score -1):

i'd like to motivate that pre-compiling is both conceptually and 'literately' (as in 'literate programming') advantageous. have a look at this code snippet:

```
from re import compile as _Re

class TYPO:

  def text_has_foobar( self, text ):
    return self._text_has_foobar_re_search( text ) is not None
  _text_has_foobar_re_search = _Re( r"""(?i)foobar""" ).search

TYPO = TYPO()
```

in your application, you'd write:

```
from TYPO import TYPO
print( TYPO.text_has_foobar( 'FOObar ) )
```

this is about as simple in terms of functionality as it can get. because this is example is so short, i conflated the way to get `_text_has_foobar_re_search` all in one line. the disadvantage of this code is that it occupies a little memory for whatever the lifetime of the `TYPO` library object is; the advantage is that when doing a foobar search, you'll get away with two function calls and two class dictionary lookups. how many regexes are cached by `re` and the overhead of that cache are irrelevant here.

compare this with the more usual style, below:

```
import re

class Typo:

  def text_has_foobar( self, text ):
    return re.compile( r"""(?i)foobar""" ).search( text ) is not None
```

In the application:

```
typo = Typo()
print( typo.text_has_foobar( 'FOObar ) )
```

I readily admit that my style is highly unusual for python, maybe even debatable. however, in the example that more closely matches how python is mostly used, in order to do a single match, we must instantiate an object, do three instance dictionary lookups, and perform three function calls; additionally, we might get into `re` caching troubles when using more than 100 regexes. also, the regular expression gets hidden inside the method body, which most of the time is not such a good idea.

be it said that every subset of measures---targeted, aliased import statements; aliased methods where applicable; reduction of function calls and object dictionary lookups---can help reduce computational and conceptual complexity.

Answer (score -4):

My understanding is that those two examples are effectively equivalent. The only difference is that in the first, you can reuse the compiled regular expression elsewhere without causing it to be compiled again.

Here's a reference for you: http://diveintopython3.ep.io/refactoring.html

> Calling the compiled pattern object's search function with the string 'M' accomplishes the same thing as calling re.search with both the regular expression and the string 'M'. Only much, much faster. (In fact, the re.search function simply compiles the regular expression and calls the resulting pattern object's search method for you.)

Comment: i didn't downvote you, but technically this is wrong: Python won't recompile anyway