# Parameterised regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

In Python, is there a better way to **parameterise strings into regular expressions** than doing it manually like this:

```
test = 'flobalob'
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for name in names:
    regexp = "%s" % (name)
    print regexp, re.search(regexp, test)
```

*This noddy example tries to match each name in turn. I know there's better ways of doing that, but its a simple example purely to illustrate the point.*

---

**The answer appears to be no, there's no real alternative. The best way to paramaterise regular expressions in python is as above or with derivatives such as `str.format()`.** I tried to write a generic question, rather than *'fix ma codez, kthxbye'*. For those still interested, I've fleshed out an example closer to my needs here:

```
for diskfilename in os.listdir(''):
    filenames = ['bob.txt', 'fred.txt', 'paul.txt']
    for filename in filenames:
        name, ext = filename.split('.')
        regexp = "%s.*\.%s" % (name, ext)
        m = re.search(regexp, diskfilename)
        if m:
          print diskfilename, regexp, re.search(regexp, diskfilename)
          # ...
```

I'm trying to figure out the 'type' of a file based on its filename, of the form `<filename>_<date>.<extension>`. In my real code, the `filenames` array is a dict, containing a function to call once a match is found.

Other ways I've considered doing it:

- **Have a regular expression in the array.** I already have an array of filenames without any regular expression magic, so I am loathe to do this. I have done this elsewhere in my code and its a mess (though necessary there).
- **Match only on the start of the filename.** This would work, but would break with .bak copies of files, etc. At some point I'll probably want to extract the date from the filename so would need to use a regular expression anyway.

---

Thanks for the responses suggesting alternatives to regular expressions to achieve the same end result. I was more interested in parameterising regular expressions for now and for the future. I never come across *fnmatch*, so its all useful in the long run.

Comment: If you ask a question about your specific case you may get a better answers.

Comment: I was more after knowing about parameterising regular expressions than fix my homework, kthxbye. See above.

Comment: I just have one comment that you probably already know but I wanted to be sure -- when using the same regular expression over and over again, you will see much better performance if you compile them first using:
    p = re.compile(s)
Your example (and others in the responses) do not do this.

Comment: Fair point, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as you build a regexp from a string, I see no other way.  But you could *parameterise the string itself* with a dictionary:

```
d = {'bar': 'a', 'foo': 'b'}
regexp = '%(foo)s|%(bar)s' % d
```

Or, depending on the problem, you could use list comprehensions:

```
vlist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
regexp = '|'.join([s for s in vlist])
```

**EDIT:** Mat clarified his question, this makes things different and the above mentioned is totally irrelevant.

I'd probably go with an approach like this:

```
filename = 'bob_20090216.txt'

regexps = {'bob': 'bob_[0-9]+.txt',
           'fred': 'fred_[0-9]+.txt',
           'paul': 'paul_[0-9]+.txt'}

for filetype, regexp in regexps.items():
    m = re.match(regexp, filename)
    if m != None:
        print '%s is of type %s' % (filename, filetype)
```

Comment: +1 I checked the documentation to make sure, there's no way to do it (other than parametrizing the string as you say). And I don't think Python needs one.

Comment: @paprika: I've clarified the example to explain a little better what I'm getting at.

@David: Couldn't find anything in the docs myself, but assumed it would be common enough for there to be something - perhaps that something is using strings in this manner.

Comment: `if m:` is sufficient in this case. In general `if obj is not None` is better than `if obj != None`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian:
Indeed, 'if m: ...' would be enough. I somehow stuck with this since I learned to avoid using the brief 'if v: ...' to check for boolean truth/falseness (which is a whole different story).  Could you elaborate on why 'is not' is better?  Just because of readability or anything else?

Comment: `is` checks for object identity (object address in memory) therefore It is highly efficient, but I use this form purely for readability.

Comment: A quick timeit test shows no performance gain from using [0-9]+ instead of \d+ -- is there another reason not to use the shorter form?

Answer (score 2):

```
import fnmatch, os

filenames = ['bob.txt', 'fred.txt', 'paul.txt']

                  # 'b.txt.b' -> 'b.txt*.b'
filepatterns = ((f, '*'.join(os.path.splitext(f))) for f in filenames) 
diskfilenames = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(''))
pattern2filenames = dict((fn, fnmatch.filter(diskfilenames, pat))
                         for fn, pat in filepatterns)

print pattern2filenames
```

Output:

```
{'bob.txt': ['bob20090217.txt'], 'paul.txt': [], 'fred.txt': []}
```

Answers to previous revisions of your question follow:

---

I don't understand your updated question but `filename.startswith(prefix)` might be sufficient in your specific case.

After you've updated your question the old answer below is less relevant.

---

1. Use `re.escape(name)` if you'd like to match a `name` literally.
2. Any tool available for string parametrization is applicable here. For example:

   ```
   import string
   print string.Template("$a $b").substitute(a=1, b="B")
   # 1 B
   ```

   Or using [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) in Python 2.6+:

   ```
   print "{0.imag}".format(1j+2)
   # 1.0
   ```

Answer (score 2):

may be [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) and [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html) modules can be of some help for you?