# Dealing with undefined global in module (python)

Tags: python, global, python-module

So I have some python code which goes like this

```
import mymodule

sum_global= mymodule.populateGlobalList("bigdict.txt")
```

and so on... with the code in **mymodule** including the method

```
def populateGlobalList(thefile):
    #do the stuff
```

So far so ok.

But elsewhere in **mymodule** I have a method that says

```
def usefulFunction(arg1, arg2):
   #lotsofstuff
   if arg1 not in sum_global:
      #add to list
```

So interpreter trips on undefined *sum_global*, which makes sense. Now usefulFunction could just take in *sum_global* as an argument, at least in theory. But *sum_global* is meant to be an English dictionary that is to be used extensively to check if words encountered are English words (or at least correctly spelled). As this occurs a lot, it would just feel unnecessarily awkward make it local.

On the other hand just declaring a global *sum_global* in the module (essentially to fool the interpreter), with the intention that this empty vessel is filled in in the program importing **mymodule**, feels completely wrong.

What is a sound design for this situation?

Comment: Globals are *per module*. Put `sum_global` in `mymodule` or pass it in as an argument to the function.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense exactly, but you could make it a class and have `sum_global` be a class attribute, then in `usefulFunction` just refer to `self.sum_global`.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but if you supply an object as a default in the `kwargs` list of a function def, the object is created once and then always supplied as the default, e.g. `usefulFunction(arg1, arg2, _cached_list={})`.

Comment: @dan-man: the problem is then that `populateGlobalList()` takes an argument. So the value isn't all that global, as there are may well different results for different files. What if there is another module that call `populateGlobalList('anotherbigdict.txt')`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters  - without knowing more details it's hard to say whether my suggestion is suitable. In principle you might want to remove the `populateGlobalList` entirely, and instead pass the filename to the `usefulFunction`, and then store everything in the cache object, indexed by both filename and `arg1`.  i.e. so that you are lazily "populating" the list.

Comment: @dan-man: yup, that's perhaps an option too. But all this sounds more like there should be a class instead, coupling state and behaviour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I don't disagree (and I didn't downvote your answer), but I think there are times when the `kwarg` approach is better for being concise. It can also be helpful when you have a true "cache" of things that you want to manage properly (although static members in a class would work too of course).

Comment: @dan-man: the `re` module follows this approach (as well as give you the OO option via `re.compile()`), and the hidden cache has bitten people in the past. See [Python re module becomes 20 times slower when looping on more than 100 different regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17325281) and [Why are uncompiled, repeatedly used regexes so much slower in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14756790). By making the cache 'visible' in the form of instances, you move responsibility to the API user. Explicit is better than implicit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each module has its own global namespace. You added `sum_global` to the wrong module, it doesn't live in `mymodule`.

Either put `sum_global` in `mymodule` or pass it in as an argument to the function that needs it.

It sounds as if you want to defer calculating the `sum_global` value until you have a filename; you could have `populateGlobalList()` set the global here; this is all in `mymodule`:

```
sum_global = None

def populateGlobalList(filename):
    global sum_global
    if sum_global is None:
        sum_global = "result of your population work"
```

This function doesn't return the data, it sets the global variable in the module (provided it hasn't already been set).

However, you should try to *avoid* creating globals like these. Since the users of your module must provide a filename, it is much better if the user code tracks the result of the `populateGlobalList()` call and *explicitly* pass this into the usefulFunction()` call:

```
import mymodule

sum_global = mymodule.populateGlobalList("bigdict.txt")

result = mymodule.usefulFunction(arg1, arg2, sum_global)
```

and retool `usefulFunction()` to require such an argument.

A next step would be for your module to use a *class* for this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._populate()

    def _populate(self):
        self.sum = "result of your population work"

    def useful_function(self, arg1, arg2):
        # do work with self.sum
```

then use that class everywhere:

```
 interesting_object = mymodule.MyClass('bigdict.txt')
 result = interesting_object.useful_function(arg1, arg2)
```