# Scope of different data types

Tags: python, types, scope

I'm trying to write a method that counts the number of distinct elements in a BST. This is my code:

```
def numDistinct(root):

    distinct = 0
    seen = {}

    def private_helper(root):

        if not root: return
        if root.val not in seen:
            seen[root.val] = root.val
            distinct += 1
        private_helper(root.left)
        private_helper(root.right)

    private_helper(root)
    return distinct
```

However, it gives me the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'distinct' referenced before assignment`. I understand the error, but it seems strange to me that `seen`, which has the same scope as `distinct`, doesn't throw the same error (even though it's referenced inside `private_helper()` before `distinct` is). To test this I changed `distinct` to a dict and set it up so I could still use it as a counter: `distinct = {'count': 0}`. The error stopped and my method started working perfectly. What is going on here? Is there a difference in scope between different data-types?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959985/why-cant-python-increment-variable-in-closure

Comment: @c3st7n Although the question provides solution to the problem, I'm more interested in why it happens, and more specifically, why it doesn't happen with dicts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python variable scope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't Python increment variable in closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959985/why-cant-python-increment-variable-in-closure)

Comment: @Sam - https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/ this might be a good thing to read, apparently this is a common question on SO and this tries to go into depth on it.

Comment: Mutating an object (e.g. a dict) is not the same thing as assigning a value to a variable. No assignment = no problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/Write Python Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009402/read-write-python-closures)

Answer (score 0):

Difference is because of mutability. Dictionary is a mutable object. See when you call distinct inside the function scope, It tries to access the object held by distinct first and tries to rebound the distinct to another object.

```
distinct += 1
or
distinct = distinct + 1
```

are same. But in case of dictionary, you rebound a name held by the dictionary. You mutate an already present object.