# Nested Function Scope

Tags: python

```
def foo():
  a = 0
  def bar():
    a += 1
  bar()
foo()
```

Why is it that this code does not execute when a is an immutable type, but does execute when it is mutable (a list, for example)?

Comment: But where are you passing **a**, its integer all the time and in function **b** , a is undefined

Comment: What do you mean "does not execute"?

Comment: This code doesn't work with lists either. `+=` is an assignment operator, which makes the second `a` local to `bar` and uninitialized.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't Python increment variable in closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21959985/why-cant-python-increment-variable-in-closure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the other answers narrate the entire story, so here's my 2 cents.
The scope does not differ between types. That's not what's happening here. 
**Rebinding a name, regardless of what that name refers to, will always cause an unbound local error to occur.**

Some types in Python are mutable (once created, a value can be changed), and list is one of them. Some are immutable, and changing a value of these types requires creating a new object.

So, with the first example,

```
def foo():
  a = 0
  def bar():
    a += 1
  bar()
foo()
```

This doesn't work because you effectively have an assignment taking place here, `a = a + 1`. You can use `non-local` to make the above work, that being besides the point.

Doing the same thing with a list:

```
def foo():
  a = []
  def bar():
    a.append(1)
  bar()
foo()
```

This does indeed work. There is no assignment taking place here.
You can't re-bind the name to a different object, but if the object is mutable, you can modify its contents.

Now, there's 2 more cases you should be aware of.

```
def foo():
  a = []
  c = []
  def bar():
    a = c + [1]
    
  bar()
  print(a)
  print(c)
foo()
```

This will work, however you should note that the `a` inside `bar()` now is local to bar, and the print() statement should reflect that.

But here's a gotcha

```py
def foo():
  a = []
  def bar():
    a = a + [1] #or even a += [1], doesn't matter
    
  bar()
  print(a)
foo()
```

This won't work! (**And it's important you contrast this snippet with the first snippet**, because that addresses why this has nothing to do with scopes. Take a minute to read it again.)

 So this doesn't work and it's important to understand it.

If there is an assignment to a variable inside a function, that variable is considered local. 
Now, in the last case, when we did `a = c + 1`, it was more like `a_local = c_nonlocal + 1`.
In this case, `a = a + 1` is `a_local = a_local + 1` and hence, that will indeed cause an error. 
This is why, **Rebinding a name, regardless of what that name refers to, will always cause an unbound local error to occur.** 
In the case earlier(The third snippet), it wasn't rebinding it - it was creating a local variable. 
In the latter case(The fourth snippet), it was infact rebinding and hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a keyword `nonlocal` which is used to access nonlocal variables.

> The nonlocal keyword is used to work with variables inside nested functions, where the variable should not belong to the inner function. --w3schools.com

```
def foo():
  a = 0
  def bar():
    nonlocal a
    a += 1
  bar()
foo()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not returning any value from either functions and the second `a` is only `local` to the function `bar()`.

Try using the nonlocal keyword like this:

```
def foo():
    a = 0
    def bar():
        nonlocal a
        a += 1
        return a
    return bar()
print(foo())
```

**Output**

> 1