# Python string.replace regular expression

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a parameter file of the form:

```
parameter-name parameter-value
```

Where the parameters may be in any order but there is only one parameter per line.  I want to replace one parameter's `parameter-value` with a new value.

I am using a line replace function [posted previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086/search-and-replace-a-line-in-a-file-in-python) to replace the line which uses Python's [`string.replace(pattern, sub)`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm%20String.Replace).  The regular expression that I'm using works for instance in vim but doesn't appear to work in `string.replace()`.

Here is the regular expression that I'm using:

```
line.replace("^.*interfaceOpDataFile.*$/i", "interfaceOpDataFile %s" % (fileIn))
```

Where `"interfaceOpDataFile"` is the parameter name that I'm replacing (/i for case-insensitive) and the new parameter value is the contents of the `fileIn` variable.

Is there a way to get Python to recognize this regular expression or else is there another way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 724, accepted):

`str.replace()` <sup>[v2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)|[v3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)</sup> does not recognize regular expressions.

To perform a substitution using a regular expression, use `re.sub()` <sup>[v2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)|[v3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)</sup>.

For example:

```
import re

line = re.sub(
           r"(?i)^.*interfaceOpDataFile.*$", 
           "interfaceOpDataFile %s" % fileIn, 
           line
       )
```

In a loop, it would be better to compile the regular expression first:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"^.*interfaceOpDataFile.*$", re.IGNORECASE)
for line in some_file:
    line = regex.sub("interfaceOpDataFile %s" % fileIn, line)
    # do something with the updated line
```

Comment: I had to pass in `flags=re.MULTILINE` as the last argument to `re.sub` in order to get this to work, which makes sense - [read about it in the docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)

Comment: regex compilations are cached ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.compile)), so compiling isn't even necessary. But as you show, if one compiles, compile outside the loop.

Comment: For anyone that wants to know the details of whether or not to compile, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452143).

Answer (score 519):

You are looking for the [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function.

```
import re
s = "Example String"
replaced = re.sub('[ES]', 'a', s)
print(replaced)
```

will print `axample atring`

Comment: Is it possible to replace with case in one line, like if first character is E change to G, if Z change it to B for example.

Comment: You can pass a string -> string function as the second argument of `re.sub`. That function will be called with each matched substring, and its result will be put in the result.

Comment: if we want case insensitive substitution, we can put `replaced = re.sub('[ES]', 'a', s, flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: When use r before the search expression?

Comment: @Timo Regex often contains backslashes, which should not be escaped "by Python". https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/6371758

Answer (score 20):

As a summary

```
import sys
import re

f = sys.argv[1]
find = sys.argv[2]
replace = sys.argv[3]
with open (f, "r") as myfile:
     s=myfile.read()
ret = re.sub(find,replace, s)   # <<< This is where the magic happens
print ret
```

Answer (score 11):

`re.sub` is definitely what you are looking for.  And so you know, you don't need the anchors and the wildcards.

```
re.sub(r"(?i)interfaceOpDataFile", "interfaceOpDataFile %s" % filein, line)
```

will do the same thing--matching the first substring that looks like "interfaceOpDataFile" and replacing it.

Comment: I need to replace the entire line because the original file will have something like:  

`interfaceOpDataFile SomeDummyFile.txt`  

and I will want to replace it with:  

    `interfaceOpDataFile SomeUsefulFile.txt`  
If I don't include the anchors how will replace know that I want to get rid of `SomeDummyFile.txt`?

Comment: Ah, I mis-understood exactly what you were doing with the replacement.  If each pair is on its own line, you still don't need the anchors explicity. `re.sub(r"(?i)(interfaceOpDataFile).*", r'\1 UsefulFile', line)`  This will take the whole line, capture the arguement name, and add it back the the substitution for you.