# How to find and replace/remove text after a specified delims with Python?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a **40GB** text file contain lines as follow:

> 55655653:foo
>
> 6654641:balh2

I've written a batch script to find and replace/remove :foo and only keep the number before that.

Batch script :

```
 @echo on

 ((for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%b in (C:\data.txt) do ( echo %%b)) >C:\dataFinal.txt
 )
pause
```

The problem of batch is that it is **not able to read the big 40GB file**

So I decided to write Python code to do the same :

```
f1 = open('data.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('dataFinal.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace(':', ''))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

What I'm missing here is how to specify the text after the: to be also removed, for batch file it is tokens=1 delims=:

**Please note the file size**

I've generated the 40GB file using Java code (maybe this info can help us with something):

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
while (in.ready()) {
   String line = in.readLine();
   PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
   out.println(initializeKeyPair(line).toString() + ":" + line );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python string.replace regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression)

Comment: Are you taling about Windows?

Comment: If you created it via Java code - why don't you just re-run it and remove the `+ ": " + line` ?

Comment: @Jon Clements i needed to have tow copies of the file one with Number:Text and one with only Number, generating this file took around 4 days. i just realized that i could add another PrintStream out to save only  initializeKeyPair(line).toString() (the Number) , so it will write both files , but too late now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `str.partition` to split the number before the first `:`

```
with open('data.txt') as fin, open('dataFinal.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(line.partition(':')[0] + '\n' for line in fin)
```

Not we're using `with` here so files are automatically closed and a generator expression to loop over `fin` split the line, take up to the first `:` then write it back to fout with a newline appended.

You may wish to specify the encoding:

```
import io

with io.open('/usr/share/dict/words', encoding='utf-8') as fin, io.open('dataFinal.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout:
    fout.writelines(line.partition(':')[0] + '\n' for line in fin)
```

Comment: Thank you, This code works, however it only wrote 140kb of the original 40GB file, maybe this cant read a big text file ?

Comment: @xhxx do you have any binary data in the file? Like an EOF marker? You might want to try `open('data.txt', 'rb')` and see what happens...

Comment: open('data.txt', 'rb') gave the same result, the file contains many different chars and encoding (china, Korean, France letters++, all keyboard symbols you can think of) the text file is UTF-8

Comment: @xhxx that's quite a significant bit of information to omit from your question (can you [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28231175/edit) your post to include that) and also state which version of Python you're using?

Comment: is there a way i can dump the first 7000 lines of the 40GB file to new text file ? so i can know if there is something that causes it to stop at line 6700? as i cant open the 40GB file in anyway using notepad, notepad++ and vim (already tried)

Comment: @xhxx  `from itertools import islice` then make the line above to end `for line in islice(fin, 7000)`

Comment: do you mean like this : `from itertools import islice
with open('RealuniqFULL.txt') as fin, open('dataFinal.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(for line in islice(fin, 7000))` Error says : `    fout.writelines(for line in islice(fin, 7000))
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @xhxx no: `fout.writelines(line.partition(':')[0] + '\n' for line in islice(fin, 7000))`

Comment: @xhxx anyway... I've edited the answer to include a version that explicitly specifies the encoding to use... try that

Comment: same issue just 6700 lines(140kb), what i meant but dump first 7000 lines is, the original number:word like copy paste the first 7000 lines

Comment: @xhxx try the version with the encoding

Comment: Thank you very much, the encoding='utf-8' solved the problem ! thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

You may easily process a data file of any size via a Batch file with this method:

```
@echo off

rem Use a subroutine to read from C:\data.txt and write to C:\dataFinal.txt
rem the subroutine must be in a separate .bat file and must be called via CMD.EXE

cmd /C call ProcessFile.bat  < C:\data.txt  > C:\dataFinal.txt
pause
```

This is ProcessFile.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process lines of input file in an endless loop
for /L %%i in ( ) do (

   rem Read next line and check for EOF
   set "line="
   set /P "line="
   if not defined line exit /B

   rem Process line read
   for /F "delims=:" %%b in ("!line!") do echo %%b

)
```

Note that this method ends reading the input file at the first empty line, but this point may be fixed, if needed.

Comment: Thanks, best answer already marked, will keep this for future use.

Answer (score 1):

You should use line.split():

```
>>> line = '55655653:foo'
>>> line, _ = line.split(':', 1)
>>> print(line)
55655653
```

Note that will also cut tailing '\n' so you should add it manually (or use print). Also, such `line, _ = line.split(':', 1)` could raise exception of `:` is not in the line.

So your code would like something like this:

```
f1 = open('data.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('dataFinal.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    line, _ = line.split(':', 1)
    f2.write(line + '\n')
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

(note that Jon Clements provided prettier way to work with files).

Comment: Thank you, how i can edit the code to read from a file ?. i've edited this f2.write(line.replace(':', '')) with f2.write(line, _ = line.split(':', 1))  but Error says :     f2.write(line, _ = line.split(':', 1))
TypeError: write() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: This code also worked, but same as Jon Clements provided, it only write 140KB of the file.