# Python only replace string which is not C++ comment

Tags: python, regex, replace

I want to deal only with string which is **NOT** `C++` comment, here is the pattern to find out `C++` comment:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'//.*?$|/\*.*?\*/|\'(?:\\.|[^\\\'])*\'|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"', re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
```

However, I don't know how to make it to work as my intention.

```
# Python 3.4.2
s = '''
/****
C++ comments
  //pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();
****/
//pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();
/*//pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();*/

// real code, I want to replace only this following line of code
pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();
'''

newS = s.replace('CreateDialogEx', 'Create')
print(newS)
```

My expected output is:

```
/****
C++ comments
  //pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();
****/
//pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();
/*//pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();*/

// real code, I want to replace only this following line of code
pResMgr->Create();
```

Comment: I would not use regex if I were you, I think you'd better iterate over your string removing what is after `//` until new line and what is after `/*` until `*/`... and THEN apply regex...

Comment: @JuniusRendel , how about pResMgr->CreateDialogEx(); // pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: @JuniusRendel, pResMgr->CreateDialogEx(); // pResMgr->CreateDialogEx(), as in your advice, I can delete comments at first, it's true, but my result should contain the original unchanged comment. What's the time to add deleted text?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression.

Comment: What I mean is the "do not process" logic would be easier and faster without using regex.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't test it, but it works it with your case and fundamentally should work. It basically goes throught the text finding newline, // or /* and then handling the cases. Really simple, no regex.

```
source_code = '''//pResMgr//->CreateDialogEx();'''

def indexOf(string, character):
    return string.index(character) if character in string else 9999999

def replaceNotInComments(string, searchFor, replaceWith):
    result = ''
    nextBreak = 0
    while True:
        nextBreak = min(indexOf(string, '\n'),
                        indexOf(string, '/*'),
                        indexOf(string, '//'))
        if nextBreak == 9999999:
            result += string.replace(searchFor, replaceWith);
            break
        result += string[0:nextBreak].replace(searchFor, replaceWith);

        if nextBreak == indexOf(string, '\n'):
            string = string[nextBreak+1:]

        if nextBreak == indexOf(string, '/*'):
            string = string[nextBreak+2:]
            result += '/*'+string[0:indexOf(string, '*/')+2]
            string = string[indexOf(string, '*/')+2:]

        if nextBreak == indexOf(string, '//'):
            string = string[nextBreak+2:]
            if result != '':
                result += '\n'  
            result += string[0:indexOf(string, '\n')+1]
            string = string[indexOf(string, '\n')+1:]


    return result

result = replaceNotInComments(source_code, 'CreateDialogEx', 'Create')
print(result)
```

Comment: your result changes '/' to '\'! here is your result: \ ****
C++ comments
  //pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();
****/
pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();
\ *//pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();*/

// real code, I want to replace only this following line of code
pResMgr->Create();

Comment: oh, that was a typo. Works now?

Comment: I found a serious issue, if source_code = '''//pResMgr->CreateDialogEx();''', your code still changes source_code

Comment: fixed again. btw, you can try to debug the code yourself

Comment: ouch, I found another bug, suppose input: source_code = 'cout << "hello, money\r\n, new line;"', then output lost '\r\n', it becomes 'cout << "hello, money
, new line;"', how can I change your code directly?

Comment: What would you want the output be? Now it basically outputs the same string since there is no comment. If you are missing the \r\n, it is probably converted  into newline in your environment, but it is there.