# how to remove star * from string using regex in pyspark

Tags: regex, pyspark

I just started PySpark, here is the task:

I have an input of:

[image]

I need to use a regex to remove punctuation and all leading or trailing space and underscore. output is all lowercase.

What I came up is not complete:

```
sentence = regexp_replace(trim(lower(column)), '\\*\s\W\s*\\*_', '')
```

and the result is:

[image]

How do I fix the regex here? I need to use regexp_replace here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: And what is the text? What is the expected result?

Comment: Try [`^[ \t_*]+|[ \t_*]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/qD0dE3/1) (or - if multiline is not on by default - `(?m)^[ \t_*]+|[ \t_*]+$`). If it does not work, please precise what exactly you need to remove and provide input/expected output samples.

Comment: what is expected is: `hi you` and `no underscore` and `remove punctuation then spaces`, thanks

Comment: with these result, the same regex will make `" The Elephant's 4 cats. "` to `"the elephants 4 cats"`

Comment: 1. Removes punctuation, changes to lower case, and strips leading and trailing spaces. 2. Only spaces, letters, and numbers should be retained.  Other characters should should be eliminated (e.g. it's becomes its).  Leading and trailing spaces should be removed after punctuation is removed.

Comment: It seems that you may use `^\W+|\W+$|[^\w\s]+|_`. The ^ and $ anchors must match line start/end. If the pattern must not overflow across lines. replace `\W+$` with `[^\w\n]+$` and the `^\W+` with `^[^\w\n]+`.

Comment: Thank you, that works amazingly

Comment: I added an answer, please consider accepting. If my answer proved helpful, please also consider upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\W+|\W+$|[^\w\s]+|_
```

The `^` and `$` anchors must match line start/end.

If the pattern must not overflow across lines, replace `\W+$` with `[^\w\n]+$` and the `^\W+`  pattern with `^[^\w\n]+`:

```
^[^\w\n]+|[^\w\n]+$|[^\w\s]+|_
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/gW2oK9/1).

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of line (if multiline option is onby default, else, try adding `(?m)` at the pattern start)
- `[^\w\n]+` - 1 or more non-word chars (non-`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) except a newline
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\n]+$` - 1 or more non-word chars at the end of the line (`$`)
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]+` - 1 or more non-word chars except any whitespace
- `|` - or
- `_` - an underscore.

**If you do not really care about Unicode** (I used `\w`, `\s` that can be made Unicode aware), you may just use a shorter, more simple pattern:

```
^[^a-zA-Z\n]+|[^a-zA-Z\n]+$|[^a-zA-Z\s]+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gW2oK9/2).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:  `sentence = column.strip(' \t\n*+_')`

If you want to remove characters only from the ends and don't care about unicode, then the basic string `strip()` function will let you pick characters to strip.  It defaults to whitespace, but you can put in whatever you want.

If you want to remove within a string you are stuck with a regular expression or, if using byte strings or Python 2, `maketrans`.

You may like to look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression) as well.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't produce what is expected. I should have mentioned this requires to use `regexp_replace`