# Regular expression for searching for extra backslashes

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which contains files locations and addresses (e.g. `%Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Safer\CodeIdentifiers\0\Hashes`)

However for some of them I have multiple backslashes in a row which I want to get rid off and replace them by only one backslashes .. is there a regular expression that I can use to identify all extra backslashes (more than one in a row) ?

Comment: @DeepSpace consider: `'\\\\\\'.replace('\\\\', '\\')`... gives you `'\\\\'` which isn't a single backslash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\\{2,}
```

Replace By:

```
\\
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OT2IjN/1)

Sample Code:

```
import re
regex = r"\\{2,}"
test_str = r"%Software\\Policies\\\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Safer\\CodeIdentifiers\\0\\Hashes\\"


subst = r"\\"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)
```

[Run it](http://ideone.com/V3RP7h)

Comment: Is there a reason you use raw string notation for the regex, but not for the teststring or the replacement?

Comment: @SebastianProske I generated the code, no reason apart ... made it look normal now

Comment: Million thanks exactly what I want, but what does `0` means in here ? `result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)`

Comment: @analeen #here the fourth argument 0 indicates means replace all... 1 means replace once, 2 means replace twice and ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you got the chance to look into the python documentation?
Regex: you'll need to know:

> '*' Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or more repetitions of the
>   preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’,
>   ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.
>
> '?' Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the
>   preceding RE. ab? will match either ‘a’ or ‘ab’.
>
> '\' Either escapes special characters (permitting you to match
>   characters like '*', '?', and so forth), or signals a special
>   sequence. so to check '\' you need to put it as '\'.  For example, to
>   match a literal backslash, one might have to write '\\' as the
>   pattern string, because the regular expression must be \, and each
>   backslash must be expressed as \ inside a regular Python string
>   literal.

If you need to know how to use regex in python:
[Python string.replace regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression)