# Regex in python 3.5

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have to replace any expression which look like:

```
"any_expression/2016.2
```

Can I do it with Regex?

String `any_expressin` can contain any character and in any length

Comment: How about this: `s/^.*(\/2016\.2\)/replaced#1/g`? PS: you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: @Jirka Picek - it doest match (there must be " in the begining).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question is "Yes".

If you want to know more about it then:

Regular expression matching your requirements is:

```
^".*(\/2016\.2)$
```

If it can be anywhere in text, just remove first and last character:

```
".*(\/2016\.2)
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression) Python doesn't recognize regex for str.replace, then you need to use `re.sub`. It should look like:

```
import re
line = re.sub(r"^\".*(\/2016\.2)$", r"replaced any expression\1", line)
```

Comment: How the following should look wirh re? `exp_cont = list(map(lambda x: x.replace("\".*\/2016\.2", "\"$vivado_path/2016.2/"), exp_cont))`

Comment: I tried: `exp_cont = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r"^\".*(\/2016\.2)", r"\"$vivado_path/2016.2", x), exp_cont))` For some reason it write the \ char in the begining of each line which was replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, this should do it:

```
".*\/2016\.2
```

In Python:

```
str.replace(".*\/2016\.2", "whatYouWantInstead");
```

Comment: Can you deomonsrarate how can I replace the any_expression to $env (string}?

Comment: but what about the first " ?

Comment: Well just add it. I dont really understand where you problem is, just make sure to escape special character with \ .

Comment: but it replace the any_expression and also the /2016.2. I want to replace only the any_expression. Foe example:                             "C:/Xilinx/Vivado/2016.2/data/ip/xpr/hdl/ram.sv"\   will be "$env/2016.2/data/ip/xpr/hdl/ram.sv"\

Comment: str.replace(".*\/2016\.2", "$env/2016.2");