# Changing Punctuation to White space(space character)

Tags: python

As of now it takes the punctuation out, but I cannot figure out how to make it add a space instead of just taking out the punctuation.
Currently I have:

```
punctuation = "!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
def remove_punct(theStr):
    theStr_sans_punct = ""
    for letter in theStr:
        if letter not in punctuation:
            theStr_sans_punct = theStr_sans_punct + letter
    return theStr_sans_punct
```

It's in a interactive textbook so it will automatically do the tests on their site.

Comment: Why not use [re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression)?

Answer (score 1):

By adding an `else` to your code:

```
punctuation = "!\"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"
def remove_punct(theStr):
    theStr_sans_punct = ""
    for letter in theStr:
        if letter not in punctuation:
            theStr_sans_punct = theStr_sans_punct + letter
        else:
            theStr_sans_punct = theStr_sans_punct + " "
return theStr_sans_punct
```

Comment: Thank you sir I do appreciate!

Comment: @john-doe Glad to help. If it solves your issue, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.