# How do I do conditionals in regex?

Tags: python, regex

Say, I want to split a string on either "。」" or " 。" , but not twice on "。」"

So for example:

```
s = "Something something。」 something something。 something。」that's great!"
```

I want to return

```
s = "Something something。」\n something something。\n something。」\nthat's great!"
```

I have trouble figuring how to split `。」` and not get `。\n」` or `。\n」\n`

Comment: Find `(。」| 。) ` replace `$1\n`

Comment: @sln Is $1 python? Sorry maybe I should have been more explicit about that

Comment: `Is $1 python` No, it's regex.

Comment: So something like this? s.replace(r'(。」| 。)', r'$1\n') .  Sorry, if I knew more about this I would be able to figure it out from your answer but I don't.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can implement the suggestions in the comments like this:

```
import re

s = "Something something。」 something something。 something。」that's great!"
pattern = re.compile(r'(。」|。)')
pattern.sub(lambda match: match.groups()[0] + '\n', s)

"Something something。」\n something something。\n something。」\nthat's great!"
```

Matches are greedy by default so that the longer pattern is used if possible (no split in the leading `。` if followed by `」`).