# Why isn't my whitespace being eliminated?

Tags: python

Why isn't the initial whitespace being removed in this example?

```py
s = ' Spain'
s = s.replace('\s*', '')
```

```py
In[1]:s
Out[1]: ' Spain'
```

I noticed this when I was removing whitespaces from a series using pandas .str.replace, so I tried in this simple example and did not understand why this does not work.

Comment: replace() takes strings, not regular expressions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression

Comment: Why not use the "strip" function (or rstrip or lstrip)?  It's much simpler.

Comment: @Paul Cornelius Because in my case there are multiple whitespaces in my strings, not just on the left and right ends

Comment: Yep, that is an excellent reason for not using strip.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = ' Spain'
>>>
>>> # Regex
>>> re.sub('\s*', '', s)
'Spain'
>>>
>>> # str.lstrip
>>> s.lstrip()
'Spain'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

- If you need to remove spaces only, use

```
s = s.replace(' ', '')
```

Note: replace does not work with regexes.

- If you need to remove whitespace characters only from the beginning and the end, use

```
s = s.strip()
```

- If you need to eliminate all of the whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines), you can use

```
s = ''.join(s.split())
```