# python multiple characters replace in string not working with pipe

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to match and replace multiple characters in a string.

```
str1 = 'US$0.18'
reg = 'AUS$|US$|HK$|MK$'
#reg = 'AUS\$|US\$|HK\$|MK\$' <-- doesn't work
#reg = 'US$' <-- this works
str1 = str1.replace(reg, '')
```

This doesn't replace `US$` which I expected to.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not using regular expressions at all, this is just plain string replacement.

Comment: You are looking for [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: (also note that `$` has special meaning in regular expressions and presumably you need to escape it)

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes.. I even tried to escape the character but same result

Comment: Yes of course, see earlier comments. This is another, better, duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720541/python-string-replace-regular-expression

Comment: Are you trying to replace text that matches ```AUS$|US$|HK$|MK$``` with ```''``` ?

Comment: @Ram yes.. that's what I wanted to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using `re.sub()`. *Since `$` has a special meaning in `re`, we need to escape it by appending a `\` in front of it.*

- `(AUS|US|HK|MK)\$` - Finds a match that has either of `AUS`, `US`, `HK` or `MK` that is followed by a `$`.
- `re.sub(r'(AUS|US|HK|MK)\$',r'', s)` - Replaces the matched string with a `''` of string `s`.

```
import re

s = "US$0.18 AUS$45 HK$96"
x = re.sub(r'(AUS|US|HK|MK)\$',r'', s)
print(x)
```

```
0.18 45 96
```