# Faster operation reading file

Tags: python, text-files

I have to process a 15MB txt file (nucleic acid sequence) and find all the different substrings (size 5). For instance:

```
ABCDEF
```

would return 2, as we have both ABCDE and BCDEF, but

```
AAAAAA
```

would return 1. My code:

```
control_var = 0
f=open("input.txt","r")
list_of_substrings=[]
while(f.read(5)!=""):
    f.seek(control_var)
    aux = f.read(5)
    if(aux not in list_of_substrings):
        list_of_substrings.append(aux)
    control_var += 1
f.close()
print len(list_of_substrings)
```

Would another approach be faster (instead of comparing the strings direct from the file)?

Comment: Should it include all offset substrings? For example if the file is "ABCDEF" should it include "ABCDE" and "BCDEF"? I don't know exactly how the internals of reading files works, but I assume there is some buffer involved which makes reading a lot more at a time cheaper.

Comment: The function should return the number of different substrings with size 5. "AAAAAAAA" would return 1.

Comment: What is the definition of a valid substring besides its length? Are all characters considered legal here? For example, should 5 consecutive empty lines be considered a valid substring of the form `\n\n\n\n\n`?

Comment: Actually the characters are a nucleic acid sequence (A's, C's, T's, G's). It's guaranteed that the input will be these letters (eventually \n will appear on the file, but should not be considered)

Comment: Well, in that case the iteration approach is much more efficient than the regular expressions approach - see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25320337/3903832) in order to setup a simple comparison between the two.

Comment: Ok. I will check that as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your definition of a legal substring is, here is a possible solution:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(?=(\w{5}))')
with open('input.txt', 'r') as fh:
    input = fh.read()
print len(set(re.findall(regex, input)))
```

Of course, you may replace `\w` with whatever you see fit to qualify as a legal character in your substring. `[A-Za-z0-9]`, for example will match all alphanumeric characters.

Here is an execution example:

```
>>> import re
>>> input = "ABCDEF GABCDEF"
>>> set(re.findall(regex, input))
set(['GABCD', 'ABCDE', 'BCDEF'])
```

**EDIT:** Following your comment above, that all character in the file are valid, excluding the last one (which is `\n`), it seems that there is no real need for regular expressions here and the iteration approach is much faster. You can benchmark it yourself with this code (note that I slightly modified the functions to reflect your update regarding the definition of a valid substring):

```
import timeit
import re

FILE_NAME = r'input.txt'

def re_approach():
    return len(set(re.findall(r'(?=(.{5}))', input[:-1])))

def iter_approach():
    return len(set([input[i:i+5] for i in xrange(len(input[:-6]))]))

with open(FILE_NAME, 'r') as fh:
    input = fh.read()

# verify that the output of both approaches is identicle
assert set(re.findall(r'(?=(.{5}))', input[:-1])) == set([input[i:i+5] for i in xrange(len(input[:-6]))])
print timeit.repeat(stmt = re_approach, number = 500)
print timeit.repeat(stmt = iter_approach, number = 500)
```

Answer (score 1):

15MB doesn't sound like a lot. Something like this probably would work fine:

```
import Counter, re
contents = open('input.txt', 'r').read()
counter = Counter.Counter(re.findall('.{5}', contents))
print len(counter)
```

**Update**

I think user590028 gave a great solution, but here is another option:

```
contents = open('input.txt', 'r').read()
print set(contents[start:start+5] for start in range(0, len(contents) - 4))

# Or using a dictionary
# dict([(contents[start:start+5],True) for start in range(0, len(contents) - 4)]).keys()
```

Comment: If speed is really **The Goal**, pre-compile the REGEXP. Will execute even faster.

Comment: This is not what @OP requested, as it doesn't take into account overlapping matches. Moreover, it should be `collections.Counter` (but using `set` would be better).

Comment: Right, he hadn't yet replied if he wanted overlapping matches when I wrote this.

Comment: He stated so in his question: "for instance `ABCDEF` would return 2".

Comment: @user3666197, [`Python` compiles and caches its regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/452143/3903832).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary, where each key is a substring.  It will take care of duplicates, and you can just count the keys at the end.

So: read through the file once, storing each substring in the dictionary, which will handle finding duplicate substrings & counting the distinct ones.

Comment: I don't think you've understood the question. I am asking whether it is better to read 5-by-5 words from the text file or read all the text /lines once and append it somewhere (string, dict..)

Answer (score 0):

Reading all at once is more i/o efficient, and using a dict() is going to be faster than testing for existence in a list. Something like:

```
fives = {}
buf = open('input.txt').read()
for x in xrange(len(buf) - 4):
    key = buf[x:x+5]
    fives[key] = 1

for keys in fives.keys():
    print keys
```