# Find and replace multiple comma/space instances in a string, Python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, text

I have a string with multiple successive instances of `,` (comma+space) that I want to replace with a single instance. Is there a clean way to do so? I suppose RegEx can be helpful.

A naive example:

```
s = 'a, b, , c, , , d, , , e, , , , , , , f
```

The desired output:

```
'a, b, c, d, e, f
```

Naturally, the text can change, so the search should be for *successive* instances of `,`.

Comment: How did you ever get such even displacement ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. This is a simplified example of something else :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So the regular expression searches for *two or more* instances of `,` (comma + space) and then in `sub` function you replace it with only a single `,`.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(,\s){2,}')

test_string = 'a, b, , c, , , d, , , e, , , , , , , f'
print re.sub(pattern, ', ', test_string)
>>> a, b, c, d, e, f
```

and without a regular expression (as *@Casimir et Hippolyte* suggested in comment)

```
test_string = 'a, b, , c, , , d, , , e, , , , , , , f'
test_string_parts = test_string.split(',')
test_string_parts = [part.strip() for part in test_string_parts if part != ' ']
print ', '.join(test_string_parts)
>>> a, b, c, d, e, f
```

Comment: Thanks. Would not this work the same: `re.sub(r'(,\s){2,}', ', ', test_string)` ? Or, is there some notable difference or corner case?

Comment: It will work as well. More info about `compile` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile

Comment: If instead of `', '` I have `'\n'` how would I adapt this find & replace? `(\\n){2,}` seems to work in https://regex101.com, but not in Python. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not only `r'\n{2,}'`?

Comment: tried `r'\n{2,}'`. It fails to catch `'\n '`in Python and in https://regex101.com

Comment: Thanks to @Casimir. This seems to work nicely: `functools.reduce( (lambda x, y: x + '\n ' + y if y else x), s.split('\n '))`

Comment: in that case `r'\n\s{2,}'`

Comment: :D well, that works for me, but perhaps I am testing with a different string

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce`:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce( (lambda x, y: x+', '+y if y else x), s.split(', '))
```

*(Where x is the carry and y the item)*

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way for your problem would be:

```
>>> s = 'a, b, , c, , , d, , , e, , , , , , , f'
>>> s = [x for x in s if x.isalpha()]
>>> print(s)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```

then, use join()

```
>>> ', '.join(s)
'a, b, c, d, e, f'
```

do it in one line:

```
>>> s = ', '.join([x for x in s if x.isalpha()])
>>> s
'a, b, c, d, e, f'
```

Just figure other way:

```
>>> s = 'a, b, , c, , , d, , , e, , , , , , , f'
>>> s = s.split()  #split all ' '(<- space)
>>> s
['a,', 'b,', ',', 'c,', ',', ',', 'd,', ',', ',', 'e,', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', ',', 'f']
>>> while ',' in s:
...     s.remove(',')
>>> s
['a,', 'b,', 'c,', 'd,', 'e,', 'f']
>>> ''.join(s)
'a,b,c,d,e,f'
```

Comment: However... this only works for single-letter variables... Please read the question :)

Comment: just add a new method

Answer (score 1):

```
s = ", , a, b, , c, , , d, , , e, , , ,  , , , f,,,,"
s = [o for o in s.replace(' ', '').split(',') if len(o)]
print (s)
```

Comment: This answer came in low quality post. Add some explanation even though code is self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

One more solution: go through the combination of the list and the same list shifted by one (in other words, by the pairs of consecutive items) and select the second item from each pair where the first (previous) item differs from the second (next) item:

```
s = 'a. b. . c. . . d. . . e. . . . . . . f'
test = []
for i in s:
    if i != ' ':
        test.append(i)


res = [test[0]] + [y for x,y in zip(test, test[1:]) if x!=y]

for x in res:
    print(x, end='')
```

yields

```
a.b.c.d.e.f
[Program finished]
```