# Detect text connected

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to detect how many times a word appears in a txt file but the word is connected with other letters.

> Detecting *Hello*
>
> > Text: **Hello**oo, how are you?
> >
> > > Expected output: 1

Here is the code I have now:

```
total = 0

with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        finded = line.find('Hello')
        if finded != -1 and finded != 0:
            total += 1

print total´
```

Do you know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try using `re.findall` from the regex module provided by Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comment by @SruthiV, you can use re.findall from `re` module,

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"Hello")

total = 0
with open('text.txt', 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
         total += len(re.findall(pattern, line))

print total
```

`re.compile` creates a pattern for regex to use, here `"Hello"`. Using `re.compile` improves programs performance and is (by some) recommended for repeated usage of the same pattern. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile).

Remaining part of the program opens the file, reads it line by line, and looks for occurrences of the pattern in every line using `re.findall`. Since `re.findall` returns a list of matches, total is updated with the length of that list, i.e. number of matches in a given line.

Note: this program will count all occurrences of `Hello`- as separate words or as part of other words. Also, it is case sensitive so `hello` will not be counted.

Answer (score 0):

For every line, you can iterate through every word by splitting the line on spaces which makes the line into a list of words. Then, iterate through the words and check if the string is in the word:

```
total = 0

with open('text.txt') as f:
    # Iterate through lines
    for line in f:
        # Iterate through words by splitting on spaces
        for word in line.split(' '):
            # Match string in word
            if 'Hello' in word:
                total += 1

print total
```