# Meaning of re.compile(r"[\w']+") in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mapreduce, bigdata

I am new to python and trying to work on big data code but not able to understand what the expression **re.compile(r"[\w']+")** means.Anyone has any idea regarding this?

This is the code that i m using.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
import re

WORD_REGEXP = re.compile(r"[\w']+")

class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        words = WORD_REGEXP.findall(line)
        for word in words:
            yield word.lower(), 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

Comment: Lookup "Python regular expressions" and just read the Python documentation regarding regular expressions. You are compiling a regular expression, then using it to search for text that matches that regular expression.

Comment: Thats what documentation is for:   https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects   and    https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile

Comment: @PatrickArtner i m not getting still how exactly that r"[\w']+" part breaks the line into words

Comment: See Zev's explanation. and use http://regex101.com for testing of regex - you even get an explanation for any pattern you provide. I find it better then pythex - and it also got a `python` regex switch

Comment: @PatrickArtner awesome resource! I've added that.

Comment: Whitespace doesn't match but alphanumerics and apostrophes do. So it breaks it up based on whitespace between the words. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a regular expression that has been compiled for faster reuse (explained in this question: [Is it worth using re.compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile)). The command re.compile is explained in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile).

Regarding the specific regex expression, this searches for groups that have alphanumerics (that's the `\w` part) or apostrophes (which is also in those square brackets) that are 1 or longer. Note that whitespace is not a match, so this, generally speaking, breaks a line into words.

See [the query](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5B%5Cw%27%5D%2B&test_string=How%27s%20it%20going%20%24%23%24%23&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) in a Python specific regex tester to try it out or on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CMGOHz/1) where they offer an explanation of any regex expression.

In the phrase `How's it going $#` this would how three matches: `How's`, `it`, `going` but wouldn't match the group of symbols.

There are lots of tutorials and even some games out there but you can start with [regexone](https://regexone.com/) to understand it better by trying some out.

Answer (score 2):

With help of `re.compile('\W')` we can remove special characters from the string.

**Example :**

```
str = 'how many $ amount spend for Car??'
pattern = re.compile('\W')
x = re.sub(pattern, ' ', str)
print(x)
```

**Result:**

> how many   amount spend for Car

*Note: Special charter **"$"** and **"?"** are removed from the string.*