# Read a text file line by line and store variables on matching specific pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.6, readline, findall

We have a large  log file containing following two lines:

```
00 LOG     |   Cycles Run:  120001
00 LOG     ! Virtual: Max> ?????????? bytes (?.???? gb), Current> 640733184 bytes (?.???? gb).

00 LOG     ! Virtual: Max> 1082470400 bytes (?.???? gb), Current> ????????? bytes (?.???? gb).

00 LOG     ! Actual: Max> ????????? bytes (?.???? gb), Current> 472154112 bytes (?.???? gb).

00 LOG     ! Actual: Max> 861736960 bytes (?.???? gb), Current> ????????? bytes (?.???? gb).
```

As the log file is big in size, we want to read line by line(not to read whole text in a buffer at a time), match specific set of patterns and pick values in separate variables.

e.g.

```
00 LOG     |   Cycles Run:  120001
```

We want o pick `120001` and store in a variable say `cycle`.

On the other hand we parse these lines:

```
00 LOG     ! Virtual: Max> ?????????? bytes (?.???? gb), Current> 640733184 bytes (?.???? gb).

00 LOG     ! Virtual: Max> 1082470400 bytes (?.???? gb), Current> ????????? bytes (?.???? gb).

00 LOG     ! Actual: Max> ????????? bytes (?.???? gb), Current> 472154112 bytes (?.???? gb).

00 LOG     ! Actual: Max> 861736960 bytes (?.???? gb), Current> ????????? bytes (?.???? gb).
```

Characters marked with `?` can be any digit.

We want to store vairables like followings:

> `640733184` in  var `virtual_cur`
>
> `1082470400` in var `virtual_max`
>
> `472154112` in var `actual_cur`
>
> `861736960` in var `actual_max`

Written a snippet in `Python 3.6` but it's printing empty list:

```
import re

filename = "test.txt"
with open(filename) as fp:  
   line = fp.readline()
   while line:
       cycle_num = re.findall(r'00 LOG     |   Cycles Run:  (.*?)',line,re.DOTALL)
       line = fp.readline()

print (cycle_num[0])
```

> NOTE: I want to pick each values in seperate variables and use it
> later on. Need to set 5 patterns one by one, pick value if it matches
> any specific pattern and put it inrespective variable.

Not sure about the wildcard matching for the second pattern.

Please suggest us a way to do this efficiently.

Comment: Do you want two variables, one for each value?

Comment: Yes. For the second variable i'm not sure how to perse it out using pattern matching with wildcards. So, did not included it in the snippet.

Comment: Note that `|` is a regex meta character for alteration. Your example regex of `r'00 LOG     |   Cycles Run:  (.*?)'` has the issue of looking for  `00 LOG     ` OR `   Cycles Run:  (.*?)` which is why it is not matching anything.

Comment: Since you have `Max>` and `Current>` in the same line, how are you deciding which one is the target to capture?

Comment: We need to search for 4 different patterns. There are two lines with `Virtual: Max>` and `Current` each with `Virtual` and `Actual` respectively. We need to do different pattern matching to select the first and the last value as mentioned.

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/L49460/1/) works for your example, but you are not clearly stating how to differentiate these values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the regex

```
(?:(?:Cycles Run:[ \t]+)|(?:Current>[ \t]+))(\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X0FGWt/1/)

You can do something along these lines:

```
import re
pat=re.compile(r'(?:(?:Cycles Run:[ \t]+)|(?:Current>[ \t]+))(\d+)')
with open('test.txt','r') as f:   
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f):
        m=pat.search(line)
        if m:
            print(line_num, m.group(0))
```

Comment: I used group(0) just because it was unclear if the OP wanted to read that value into a dict or what. It identifies which value was captured.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here you have matched the pattern using `Current>`. 

What if we have patterns like this: 

`00 LOG ! Virtual: Max> ?????????? bytes (?.???? gb), Current> 640733184 bytes (?.???? gb).`

`00 LOG ! Virtual: Max> 1082470400 bytes (?.???? gb), Current> ????????? bytes (?.???? gb).`

`00 LOG ! Actual: Max> ????????? bytes (?.???? gb), Current> 472154112 bytes (?.???? gb).`

`00 LOG ! Actual: Max> 861736960 bytes (?.???? gb), Current> ????????? bytes (?.???? gb).`

 We need to pick up these four values in four different variables.

Comment: Please update your question with those strings. It is unclear in a comment what you are looking for.

Comment: Updated the original question! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use an alternation here with two lookbehinds:

```
(?<=Cycles Run:  )\d+|(?<= Current>  )\d+
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/dBHUhR/1).

---

Python example:

```
import re
text = '''
00 LOG     |   Cycles Run:  120001
00 LOG     !   Virtual: Max> 1082470400 bytes (1.0081 gb), Current>  640733184 bytes (0.5967 gb)
'''

pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=Cycles Run:  )\d+|(?<= Current>  )\d+')
matches = re.findall(pattern,text)
num_cycle = matches[0]
current = matches[1]

print(num_cycle,current)
```

Prints:

```
120001 640733184
```

As you are repeating the process in a loop, it is recommended to use `re.compile` to compile the pattern only once before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here we search for some identifier (like `cycles` and apply a different regex)

```
import re
with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'Cycles',line):
            m=re.findall(r'\d+$',line)
        else:
            m=re.findall(r'Current>  (\d+)',line)
        print(m)
```

Comment: This works but seems rather inefficient. The patterns should at least be compiled before the loop.

Comment: @Unbearable The doc states `the module-level matching functions are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions.` Since it's the same expression, I think caching will help. Also, The regex is really simple without lookaheads/behinds, which will save lots of time. This is obviously not elegant.

Comment: You are right, it does appear the patterns are [cached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452143/3390419), my bad. Yes, the lookarounds can be expensive however only one `re` function is needed if using them.