# Finding all occurrences of a list of words in a text using regex by trying to join words with "|" does not work as expected

Tags: python, regex

I need to find all occurrences of a list of words in a text using regex. For example, given the words:

```
words = {'i', 'me', 'my'}
```

and some

```
text = 'A book is on the table. I have a book on the table. My book is on the table. There is my book on the table.'
```

should return `result = ["I", "My", "my"]`

I'm using this:

```
re.findall(r"'|'.join(words))", text,flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

But it's returning an empty list.

Also if I use this:

```
re.findall(r"(?=("+'|'.join(words)+r"))", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
```

returns:

```
['i', 'I', 'My', 'i', 'i', 'my']
```

which is incorrect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481198/python-match-multiple-substrings-in-a-string

Comment: Please be more specific about what the issue is. Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I will do:

This regex will get values from my list, that can be preceded or exceeded by not a word e.g: `Is it I?`

```py
import re

words = ["I", "am", "my"]
text = "A book is on the table. I have a book on the table. My book is on the table. There is my book on the table."

pattern = r'\W.*?({})\W.*?'.format('|'.join(words))
s = re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the way you define the regex. You are not joining the words, you are using a regex `"'|'.join(words)"`, which leads in no matches.

```
>>> x = r"'|'.join(words)"
>>> x
"'|'.join(words)"
```

You can rewrite it as

```
>>> re.findall(r"\b({})\b".format('|'.join(words)), text[0], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
['I', 'My', 'my']
```

Note [`\b`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) here is a world boundary that matches the empty string at the beginning or end of a word needed in order to only match full words.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.compile('|'.join(map(lambda x: '\\b' + x + '\\b', words)), 
           flags=re.IGNORECASE)
  .findall(text[0])
```

Putting `\b` on either side of words keeps "I" from matching things like "is".