# How can I find in a string that contain words in list1 then append it in list2

Tags: python, string, list

Here is the `list1`, `string` and the `list2` should be

```
list1 = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST"]
```

and

```
string = NORTHSOUTHWESTEASTWEST
```

I want

```
list2 = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "WEST", "EAST", "WEST"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicates with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481198/python-match-multiple-substrings-in-a-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regexp matching (via combining `list1` items to regex pattern):

```
import re

list1 = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST"]
string = 'NORTHSOUTHWESTEASTWEST'
res = re.findall(fr'{"|".join(list1)}', string)
print(res)
```

---

```
['NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'WEST', 'EAST', 'WEST']
```

Comment: Though practically the same as the other answer, this one is more clean.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions.

For example:

```
import re 

list1 = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST"]
s = "NORTHSOUTHWESTEASTWEST"

pattern = re.compile("(" + r"|".join(list1) + ")" )

print( pattern.findall(s))
```

Output:

```
['NORTH', 'SOUTH', 'WEST', 'EAST', 'WEST']
```