# Get Href by text using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using "requests" and "beautifulsoup" to search for all the href links from a webpage with a specific text. I've already made it but if the text comes in a new line, beautifulsoup doesn't "see" it and don't return that link.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpageAdress, "lxml")

path = soup.findAll('a', href=True, text="Something3")
print(path)
```

Example:

Like this, it returns Href of Something3 text:

```
...
<a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">Something3</a>
...
```

Like this, it doesn't return the Href of Something3 text:

```
...
<a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">
Something3</a>
...
```

The difference is that Href text (Something3) is in a new line.
And i can't change HTML code because i'm not the webmaster of that webpage.

Any idea how can i solve that?

Note: i've already tried to use soup.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')  but i get the error  NoneType' object is not callable.

Comment: Thank you all with your answers. You helped me  a lot! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to find any text that contains `"Something3":

```
html = '''<a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">Something3</a>

<a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">
Something3</a>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

path = soup.findAll('a', href=True, text=re.compile("Something3"))

for link in path:
    print (link['href'])
```

Comment: What does re.compile do?

Comment: read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452104/is-it-worth-using-pythons-re-compile). But basically allows for matching/looking for patterns, versus trying to find a keyword exclusively. If we did `text="Something3"`, have that `\n` would not return anything because it's not exact. So we would rather look for if that substring is within the whole string. regex is just a way to do that

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:contains` pseudo class with bs4 4.7.1

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '<a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">Something3</a>'
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
links = [link.text for link in soup.select('a:contains(Something3)')]
print(links)
```

Comment: Neet trick! Now I have to learn about selecting with pseudo classes....

Comment: @JackFleeting Yeah. I am really pleased with the new bs4. It has so many more awesome features.

Comment: Din't know that. Thanks! ;)

Comment: No worries. I would expect it to be faster than regex but haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

And a solution without regex:

```
path = soup.select('a')
if path[0].getText().strip() == 'Something3':
print(path)
```

Output:

```
[<a href="page1/somethingC.aspx">
Something3</a>]
```

Comment: Thanks you for your helping answer