# Regex to map character to a function of that character

Tags: python, regex

I want a function using regex that will map certain punctuation characters (these: `.`, `,`, `(`, `)`, `;`, `:`) to a function of that character. Specifically, it will put a space on either side.

For example, it would map the string "Hello,  this is a test string." to "Hello ,  this is a test string . "
This is what I have right now:

```
import re

def add_spaces_to_punctuation(input_text)
    text = re.sub('[.]', ' . ', input_text)
    text = re.sub('[,]', ' , ', text)
    text = re.sub('[:]', ' : ', text)
    text = re.sub('[;]', ' ; ', text)
    text = re.sub('[(]', ' ( ', text)
    text = re.sub('[)]', ' ) ', text)
    return text
```

This works as intended, but is pretty unwieldy/hard to read. If I had a way to map each punctuation characters to a function of that character in a single regex line it would improve it significantly. Is there a way to do this with regex? Sorry if its something obvious, I'm pretty new to regex and don't know what this kind of thing would be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = re.sub(r"(\.|\,|\(|\)|\;|\:)", lambda x: f' {x.group(1)} ', text)
```

It uses a capture group to capture whatever the character may be and then map that to the same character with a space on either side using a lambda expression (see https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp for more info).

The part of the regex in parenthesis (in this case the whole thing) is what gets captured and `x.group(1)` will give you the captured character.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
import re

recmp = re.compile(r'[.,:;()]')

def add_spaces_to_punctuation(input_text):
    text = recmp.sub(r' \1 ', input_text)

    return text
```

Also, taking performance into consideration and according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452142/12195738), it should be faster if you need to run it often.